# How can I decode data with Base64 in IPhone

Tags: java, iphone, decoding

Hi My friend is using Base64 encoding standard in java.

I am using IPhone how can I decode the data. and viceversa.
There is  org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64  in java

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk. Duplicate

Answer (score 1):

TouchCode has http://touchcode.googlecode.com/hg/Support/Common/Base64Transcoder.c (and .h)

Answer (score 0):

There is also some quite simple code you can use here:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour

Another interesting way to do it, using OpenSSL:

http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/03/12/base64_cocoa/

Answer (score 0):

use this code   [base64](http://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64)(github.com/nicklockwood/Base64)