# encode-decode image data with base64

Tags: iphone

I am try to make iPhone application to encode-decode an images (NSData format).

```
 NSData imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);`
```

How can I do, please give some source code.
Thank you!

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197362/converting-nsdata-to-base64 , and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892223/how-can-i-decode-data-with-base64-in-iphone

Answer (score 1):

[CocoaDev:BaseSixtyFour](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour)

Comment: Keep reading. There's an `NSData` category that extends encoding/decoding functionality.