# How do i transform a file(any type of file) in Base64 to send to a web service Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-applications

I need to send a files to a XML web service. The web service only accepts the file in a base64 format and rebuilds it in the back end.  I need to know how do i convert a file to base64 in Objective C.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk

Comment: a quick search would reveal many answers.... you should at least look for an answer before posting a new question...

Comment: I already wrote code for NSString to base64 for AES Encryption. What I need is to know is how can I convert any type of file into base64 or at least into a NSString sow i can send it to a web service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below SO post

[How do I do base64 encoding on iphone-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk)

[How can I decode data with Base64 in IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892223/how-can-i-decode-data-with-base64-in-iphone)

[How to Base64 encoding on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882277/how-to-base64-encode-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);       
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];  
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  
NSData *imagedata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewimage);  
NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64Encoding];
```

where view is the view where lines are drawn.