# Converting NSData to base64

Tags: iphone, base64, nsdata

How to convert `NSData` to `base64`. I have `NSData` and want to convert into `base64` how can I do this?

Comment: This is very close to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk

Comment: so, why do we need to convert NSData to base 64 in general?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**EDIT**

As of OS X 10.9 / iOS 7, this is built into the frameworks.

See `-[NSData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:]`

---

Prior to iOS7/OS X 10.9:

Matt Gallagher wrote [an article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) on this very topic. At the bottom he gives a link to his embeddable code for iPhone.

On the mac you can use the OpenSSL library, on the iPhone he writes his own impl.

Comment: There seems to be a small issue in Matts code: In `void *NewBase64Decode` line 128, `j += accumulateIndex - 1;` has to be surrounded with `if (accumulatedIndex > 0) {...}`. Otherwise, if the encoded stream contains invalid (e.g. `\r\n`) chars at the end, the last character of the decoded text may get lost. This caused strange issues in my code doing line based decoding of IMAP responses...

Comment: It turns out there has been a function to do this since iOS4, but it was never released publicly until iOS 7. If imageData is an instance of NSData, then simply...

[imageData base64Encoding];

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSData_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

Answer (score 28):

```
//from: http://cocoadev.com/BaseSixtyFour
+ (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData {

    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

  static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

  NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
  uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
  for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
    NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
    for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
      value <<= 8;

      if (j < length) {
        value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
      }
    }

    NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
    output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
    output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
    output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
  }

  return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 21):

As an update, the iOS7 SDK has a category on `NSData (NSDataBase64Encoding)` with methods

```
-[NSData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:]
-[NSData initWithBase64EncodedString:options:]
-[NSData initWithBase64EncodedData:options:]
-[NSData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:]
```

Should avoid having to roll your own category method

Comment: Wow, great to hear! Every time when it comes to base64, I'm wondering why it is not present in standard libs of so many languages...

Comment: These are available back to iOS 4, iOS 7 SDK just made them public

Comment: Sorry, there are functionally equivalent methods available back to iOS 4(initWithBase64Encoding and base64Encoding)

Comment: Can you give an example in your answer on how to use it ?

Comment: One example is sending binary data to a REST web service interface. E.g. Say I have a photo photo property on a Person object, to send it via JSON, I can convert the `-[Person photo]` NSData property to an NSString by `-[[Person photo] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]` and so can be serialised by `NSJSONSerialization`

Answer (score 6):

Super easy drop-in Google library code [here.](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMStringEncoding.m)

Just use `+rfc4648Base64StringEncoding` to get an instance, then use the `encode`/`decode` functions.

It's a beautiful thing. (Don't forget to grab the header file and the `GTMDefines.h` header from the root, though.)

Answer (score 4):

Its not easy. As in there's no built in support for this in c or obj-c. Here's what Im doing (Which is basically having the CL do it for me):

```
- (NSString *)_base64Encoding:(NSString *) str
{
    NSTask *task = [[[NSTask alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSPipe *inPipe = [NSPipe pipe], *outPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    NSFileHandle *inHandle = [inPipe fileHandleForWriting], *outHandle = [outPipe fileHandleForReading];
    NSData *outData = nil;

    [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/openssl"];
    [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"base64", @"-e", nil]];
    [task setStandardInput:inPipe];
    [task setStandardOutput:outPipe];
    [task setStandardError:outPipe];

    [task launch];

    [inHandle writeData:[str dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [inHandle closeFile];

    [task waitUntilExit];

    outData = [outHandle readDataToEndOfFile];
    if (outData)
    {
        NSString *base64 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:outData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
        if (base64)
            return base64;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
NSString *b64str = [strToConvert _base64Encoding:strToConvert];
```

And this isn't my code - I found it here: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour and it works great. You could always turn this into a +() method.

Oh, and to get your NSData to an NSString for this method:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: On the mac it isn't necessary to spawn a process - you can directly use libcrypto.  On the iPhone, is /usr/bin/openssl present?

Answer (score 2):

iOS has always included built in support for base64 encoding and decoding. If you look at `resolv.h` you should see the two functions `b64_ntop` and `b64_pton` . The Square [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/tree/master/SocketRocket) library provides a reasonable example of how to use these functions from objective-c.

These functions are pretty well tested and reliable - unlike many of the implementations you may find in random internet postings.
Don't forget to link against `libresolv.dylib`.

If you *link* against the iOS 7 SDK, you can use the newer methods `initWithBase64Encoding:` and `base64EncodedDataWithOptions:`. These exist in previous releases, but were private. So if you link against the 6 SDK, you may run into undefined behavior. This would be an example of how to use this only when linking against the 7 SDK:

```
#ifndef __IPHONE_7_0
    // oh no! you are using something unsupported!
    // Call and implementation that uses b64_pton here
#else
    data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64Encoding:string];
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code above to meet my needs, building an HTTP POST.  I was able to skip the NSString step, and include line breaks in the BASE64 code, which at least one web server found more palatable:

```
#define LINE_SIZE   76

//originally from: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour
// via joshrl on stockoverflow

- (void) appendBase64Of: (NSData *)inData to:(NSMutableData *)outData {
    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[inData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [inData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    uint8_t buf[LINE_SIZE + 4 + 2];
    size_t n = 0;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        buf[n + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        buf[n + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        buf[n + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        buf[n + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        n += 4;
        if (n + 2 >= LINE_SIZE) {
            buf[n++] = '\r';
            buf[n++] = '\n';
            [outData appendBytes:buf length:n];
            n = 0;
        }
    }
    if (n > 0) {
        buf[n++] = '\r';
        buf[n++] = '\n';
        [outData appendBytes:buf length:n];
    }
    return;
}
```