# NSData to NSString using initWithBytes:length:encoding

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uiimage, nsdata

I have some image data (jpeg) I want to send from my iPhone app to my webservice. In order to do this, I'm using the NSData from the image and converting it into a string which will be placed in my JSON.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
    NSString *secondString = [[NSString alloc]  initWithBytes:[result bytes]
                                                    length:[result length] 
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Where result is of type NSData. However, secondString appears to be null even though result length returns a real value (like 14189). I used this method since result is raw data and not null-terminated.

Am I doing something wrong? I've used this code in other areas and it seems to work fine (but those areas I'm currently using it involve text not image data).

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For binary data, better to encode it using Base64 encoding then decode it in you webservice. I use NSData+Base64 class downloaded from [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html), this reference was also taken from Stackoverflow, an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197362/converting-nsdata-to-base64/2197658#2197658) made by @Ken (Thanks Ken!).

Comment: I tried Base64 but got some illegal JSON characters (before). I'll look closer into the encoding and see if I can find the error.

Comment: Sweet, it worked. Looks like the base64 function I was using needed a little tweaking. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are not converting the data to a string. You are attempting to interpret it as a UTF-8 encoded string, which will fail unless the data really is a UTF-8 encoded string. Your best bet is to encode it somehow, perhaps with Base64 as Manny suggests, and then decode it again on the server.

Comment: OK. Yeah, I wasn't sure if this was possible. I'm trying to address some code in an external library and wasn't sure if this made sense. Thanks.

Comment: Just a note for any future readers. From the wiki on UTF-8: "Not all sequences of bytes are valid UTF-8." And looking more closely at the definition of UTF-8, I can see where there's a problem. It seems that you run into problems by taking binary data (that is not UTF-8) and trying to interpret it as UTF-8. I looked around Stack Overflow and couldn't find anyone who explicitly said this.