# how to convert imagedata to base64 in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to convert imagedata into base64 my code is:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BombTense.png"];
NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

I want to convert these imagedate into base64 and pass it to wsdl tool generated webservices 
  code. please help me.

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197362/converting-nsdata-to-base64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html
by Matt Gallagher