# save data downloaded from internet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

here's the thing: I download a bunch of data in JSON format. I put that into an array of dictionaries. Then, I save to disk. One dictionary stores a link to some image. What I would like to do is to store also the actual image (not the link!) along with rest of the data. How would you start? Which way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would download the image and save the local path alongside the URL path.

However, if you're going for one big file, you could always [base64-encode it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197362/converting-nsdata-to-base64/5587698#5587698).

I think using the filesystem directly and saving your local path would be more efficient and effective than one monolithic file, as you'll save a lot of parsing and encode/decode time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start from this tutorial : [SimpleFTPExample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)