# Store images in ICloud

Tags: iphone

Hi guys first of all thanks for such a media which is helping all the developers allover globe.Now coming to my question,I want to Store images in icloud and retrive them in my application. I am able to store text in icloud but not able to store images here is the link which i followed:

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.raywenderlich.com%2F6015%2Fbeginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1&ei=_N17T7-tF4yyiQf61bSmCQ&usg=AFQjCNERLzDywf_B2LdeIrssjc4hDB7ZMQ&sig2=hVY9x0c7ezSfZOIjx-HFJQ

It is working fine but i am able to store text only not the image so please help me out 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: got any solution?? dear?

Answer (score 0):

When I have moved images back and forth from a server to an iOS app, I have used base64 encoding/decoding (there are many libraries out there).  I would try encoding the image into a base64 string on the device and then sending it (as text) to iCloud.

There are several NSData categories out there that deal with converting NSData into a base64 encoded string.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197362/converting-nsdata-to-base64) for a solution to the encoding.

According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288238/storing-pictures-in-icloud), however, you should store it as a document unless it is very small.

Comment: Try using NSKeyedarchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver the data then send it to icloud....and at the fetching time use the same key value to get the data