# Storing pictures in iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud

I'm currently working on a concept for a new iPhone app, the would involve some very basic profile system.

Since all the other data will be stored in iCloud, I was wondering if it would be possible to store pictures in the cloud too.
I see that the storage per app is only 1MB, so this seems extremely low to store pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1 MB limit is for Key-Value storage only (and KV storage is inappropriate for images for other reasons, too). If you use the [Documents in the Cloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForDocumentsIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH2-SW1) APIs, your app can store a large number of large files, limited only by how much space the user has (or hasn't) paid for. (Though it's wise to use that space judiciously and efficiently, as your potential customers won't be happy if your app alone causes them to blow the storage limits on their account.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it would be multiple profile images about 50x50, I will check how much space it takes up, and make the image optional so users can choose not to use it.