# error trying to parse NSData using NSXMLParser delegates

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

I have some xml that contains a **BASE 64 ENCODED PNG IMAGE** I am trying to parse this into an object of some type.. for the moment into a `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`, however I am currently unsuccessful doing so.

This is part of my parse delegate:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"GUI"]){
        parsedGUIMutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:attributeDict];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"GUI"]) {
        [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries addObject:parsedGUIMutableDictionary];

    }


}
```

Once this is done there are no values saved into the dictionary so it's just empty... I have added a breakpoint in both if statements and when the first if statement is entered 
**attributeDict** is empty.

This is what the xml looks like:

```
<IC>

  <Reps>

    <GUI>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAiwAAAFKCAMAAAF+68SXAAADAFBMVEUAAAAAADMAAGYAAJkAAMwA

AP8AMwAAMzMAM2YAM5kAM8wAM/8AZgAAZjMAZmYAZpkAZswAZv8AmQAAmTMAmWYAmZkAmcwAmf8A

zAAAzDMAzGYAzJkAzMwAzP8A/wAA/zMA/2YA/5kA/8wA//8zAAAzADMzAGYzAJkzAMwzAP8zMwAz

MzMzM2YzM5kzM8wzM/8zZgAzZjMzZmYzZpkzZswzZv8zmQAzmTMzmWYzmZkzmcwzmf8zzAAzzDMz

zGYzzJkzzMwzzP8z/wAz/zMz/2Yz/5kz/8wz//9mAABmADNmAGZmAJlmAMxmAP9mMwBmMzNmM2Zm

M5lmM8xmM/9mZgBmZjNmZmZmZplmZsxmZv9mmQBmmTNmmWZmmZlmmcxmmf9mzABmzDNmzGZmzJlm

zMxmzP9m/wBm/zNm/2Zm/5lm/8xm//+ZAACZADOZAGaZAJmZAMyZAP+ZMwCZMzOZM2aZM5mZM8yZ

M/+ZZgCZZjOZZmaZZpmZZsyZZv+ZmQCZmTOZmWaZmZmZmcyZmf+ZzACZzDOZzGaZzJmZzMyZzP+Z

/wCZ/zOZ/2aZ/5mZ/8yZ///MAADMADPMAGbMAJnMAMzMAP/MMwDMMzPMM2bMM5nMM8zMM//MZgDM

ZjPMZmbMZpnMZszMZv/MmQDMmTPMmWbMmZnMmczMmf/MzADMzDPMzGbMzJnMzMzMzP/M/wDM/zPM

/2bM/5nM/8zM////AAD/ADP/AGb/AJn/AMz/AP//MwD/MzP/M2b/M5n/M8z/M///ZgD/ZjP/Zmb/

Zpn/Zsz/Zv//mQD/mTP/mWb/mZn/mcz/mf//zAD/zDP/zGb/zJn/zMz/zP///wD//zP//2b//5n/

/8z///8AAAANDQ0aGhooKCg1NTVDQ0NQUFBdXV1ra2t4eHiGhoaTk5OhoaGurq67u7vJycnW1tbk

5OTx8fH///8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAAAAAAABGUgBlAAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAACXRFWHRDb21tZW50AACJKo0G

AAALi0lEQVR4nO2da3LiOBRGU8UO2EzvL396CbORbCIrcJVN3p0HXsXwatrAZ1uWr2TJPocehhAh

Xz4fhCMU564w4W5A24cHk25qm246GNLNyqabDvKtJv9uOvKcppsBPU3QjY9+s69mdSKNanbcF8lk

M303w6CbK9b//g3o5semmrJMqpsqqWqidtPVrI8h3Xw7dTOGOXYzoJe6/SB90KG+RS1F7dzL/YBe

/WqhF3rJffsdfff5Yq1eLXrpOWqidtPVrI8h3Xw7dWqidtPVrI8h3Xw7dWqidPaL3kuVUC1Ovbz1

Hn/39vLLoZfgh9/z6+WahwNDHxWmlsKnlFC1dH080EqoWnygFo1bLe0/67UwbE79RH65HBnwZBeV

y4GVI1Fq8diII5619D3vOL6s/LfVx7haWktaeC62UIuGWjTUosm6loBQi4ZaNHdfB74tGfwTzN9a

Tv/flLaMqcWUsuyYT2snTC2VVzCBckmpllnuo6ddxJuRWNXy5vmabOIzxtx93PJcVZW425l3z2eS

1HvA1AU0mH0ttde0d8g5+MGPClNL7VNKwM8Dhj8oUC0dy/zbCfbZhMdjMqrFa250/7gQtXhVUoTJ

xauQYim1DC9pGbUMh1o0oWsZ8rnaknIZwuJqcfy4cXG5OLLQWvqWqONLC9SiiV5Lx+TTonPpgFpk

G8a6Fqjl1DChY6nrhtSSai3naawEfPnXnFqohVrGQy0aatFQi4ZaNPnUcv5Vz1+Nf8c1bd+2a9r6

a9Eccqk353JNKLtradsXp/u/jZfXbUfUYsuuGGqhFpNa1tRCLdQSuxaDZaobw1o6fs/fjYRqGb+P

1la1lH65iPW3VVW9jVm/W37a7SML8jn21lCLZgm12PPQIPjG8omlkYvv71q5k1EsRbxUsoqliJZK

XrEUsVLJLJYiUiq5xeL1buvBuFgCnnmlhTxiuY8azGqVSSxGVbhDLBJikWQXi+tJuMaRXSxxIBYJ

sUjyjsX3d1V7NsdxSwvEIiEWyVxiWXn+SZGWzRGL3Nx8YjGFWCRzjMUgolnGMnLWakaHc9jS24RY

ZBNikU0MZq3mHosnxCIhFsmiYnGcteK4pQ1ikRCLZKGxdE7PzHS+hVhkE4PpGWKREItsTiy3s1bL

PZzDFq/mxEIs7s2JhVjcm2cRS3yIRUIsEmKREIuEWCTEIiEWCbFIiEUyJpb12vW6uHv5S/n8ki5V

Wf2MimXg7m82/yw3P/++WludBc6Kr3I7SSxJc/rLscRyyemUf8Ryyf6PxhLLDftMKmK5xvtFdHrH

HfagjGLxfBHNPRbPF9H8Y8GWG3gRSXgRSZJ8EdX1dkc9IUnG8nYsavQZScdCLIotsQjKT4+foI1j

uZhvSSCWp3J/HSuWj/csLttTvczlSohFQiwSYpEQy5RkE0vNSaclMVPJKJaaWCQRz1CeUyx1PFly

iqWIJ0tWsdTRZMkqliKaLHnFUseSJa9YiliyZBZLHUmWzGIpIsmSXSyRtkMsEmKRjIwlzFmUW7d2

Tyxqa7nEEhtikRCLhFgkxCIhFkl2sVieiryN+wxjiUJ+sWCLIs7hLrFIiEVCLBJikWQdS7iI8o4l

0N8szXC+hVgkvIgkxCIhFgmxSIhFQiyS9ljsQsp8YsHgD+7MZxpK3y5qbBG3bSEWCbFIiEVCLBJi

kcwzlpGrhOY630IsYSAWCbFIiEVCLBJikcw9Fq/lMPOfWFj8NFRbc2zpaT4AYpEQi4RYJMQiWVIs

AyJaVCyuq4TmP99CLBbN/0IsEmKREIuEWCTEIlluLB0PXtbEwoDFU//ZFNtLarF0Lp5ari09EIuE

WCTEIiEWCbFIiKW4XSXEfMvxG8TiBrFIiEVCLBJikRCLhFgkxCIhFgmxSIhFQiyS7GKJA7FIiEVC

LBJikRCLhFgkxCIhFgmxSIhFQiwSYpEQi4RYJMQiIRYJsUiIRTImlvWv9fX1Wl8vKpZi7Xxd3H2f

+Pra/UuV7+ixPJ+oqpeX58blZX359aSX57J8GxTLXfM5+sRyftBb+Sk6SYb38k8xRSxFsSnfG338

SiyXYvM0TSx7Y/6xLpNjM1Est50kwyGXd2K54ugLsVxBLBJikRCLhFgkxCIZGUtdEEtLLEXjTmI5

QCx7OmIpGt8ilqsGxNIBsUiIpQNikRBLB8QiIZYOiEWyhFj8IZaBj7+IZVvv2U5IkrGUZbW7lJuJ

</GUI>

  </Reps>

</IC>
```

I am hoping someone knows how to help me get the data from this XML so I can then use something similar to the code below to decode my png

```
[Base64 initialize];
NSData *data = [Base64 decode:img];
cell.image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to bother with the `NSDictionary`. I'm not at my Mac, but try something like:

1. Implement the `foundCharacters` callback in your delegate ([NSXMLParserDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate)).
2. In the `foundCharacters` implementation check if you are between the `didStartElement` and `didEndElement` calls for the **GUI** element: if you are, append the characters to an `NSMutableString` instance.
3. In `didEndElement` you can then initialize an `NSData` instance using the `NSMutableString` using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020307/how-to-decode-convert-a-base64-string-to-nsdata).

That should get you where you need to be.

Comment: There is something in the apple docs but im not sure what they are doing with the mutableString value **- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if (!currentStringValue) {
        // currentStringValue is an NSMutableString instance variable
        NSMutableString *currentStringValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:50];
    }
    [currentStringValue appendString:string];
}**

Comment: You don't want to create a new instance every time: `foundCharacters` can be called multiple times depending on the chunks it fetches. Create the instance in `didStartElement` and then just call `appendString` in `foundCharacters`.