# How to set HTTP request body using AFNetwork's AFHTTPRequestOperationManager?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, afnetworking

I am using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager (2.0 AFNetworking library) for a REST POST request.  But the manager only have the call to set the parameters.

```
-((AFHTTPRequestOperation *)POST:(NSString *)URLString
                  parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                     success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                     failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

I need to set HTTP request body with a string as well.  How can I do it using the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager?  Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding code as shown below:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  timeoutInterval:10];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"Basic: someValue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setValue: @"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"JSON responseObject: %@ ",responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}];
[op start];
```

Comment: But how to do with `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`?

Answer (score 7):

for AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

```
[requestOperationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"your Content Type" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[requestOperationManager.requestSerializer setValue:@"no-cache" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cache-Control"];

// Fill parameters
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"name"        : @"John",
                             @"lastName"    : @"McClane"};

// Customizing serialization. Be careful, not work without parametersDictionary
[requestOperationManager.requestSerializer setQueryStringSerializationWithBlock:^NSString *(NSURLRequest *request, NSDictionary *parameters, NSError *__autoreleasing *error) {

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSString *argString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return argString;
}];

[requestOperationManager POST:urlString parameters:parameters timeoutInterval:kRequestTimeoutInterval success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    if (success)
        success(responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    if (failure)
        failure(error);
}];
```

Answer (score 6):

Check what that convenience method (POST:parameters:success:failure) is doing under the hood and do it yourself to get access to actual NSMutableRequest object.

I'm using AFHTTPSessionManager instead of AFHTTPRequestOperation but I imagine the mechanism is similar.

This is my solution:

1. Setup Session Manager (headers etc)
2. Manually create NSMutable request and add my HTTPBody, basically copying-pasting code inside that convenience method. Looks like this:

   ```
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:<url string>] absoluteString] parameters:parameters];

   [request setHTTPBody:[self.POSTHttpBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   __block NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * __unused response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
       if (error) {
          // error handling
       } else {
           // success
     }
   }];

   [task resume];
   ```

Answer (score 4):

If you dig a little in sources of AFNetworking you will find that in case of `POST` method parameters are set into body of your HTTP request.

Each key,value dictionary pair is added to the body in form `key1=value1&key2=value2`. Pairs are separated by & sign.

Search for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in **AFURLRequestSerialization.m**.

In case of a string which is only a string, not key value pair then you might try to use `AFQueryStringSerializationBlock` http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.3/Classes/AFHTTPRequestSerializer.html#//api/name/setQueryStringSerializationWithBlock: but this is only my guess.

Answer (score 4):

You could create your own custom subclass of `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`, and set this as the requestSerializer for your `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`.

In this custom requestSerializer, you could override

```
- (NSURLRequest *)requestBySerializingRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request         
                               withParameters:(id)parameters 
                                        error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error;
```

Inside your implementation of this method, you'll have access to the `NSURLRequest`, so you could do something like this

```
- (NSURLRequest *)requestBySerializingRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request     
                               withParameters:(id)parameters 
                                        error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error  
{    
    NSURLRequest *serializedRequest = [super requestBySerializingRequest:request withParameters:parameters
     error:error];
    NSMutableURLRequest *mutableRequest = [serializedRequest mutableCopy];          
    // Set the appropriate content type
    [mutableRequest setValue:@"text/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];              
    // 'someString' could eg be passed through and parsed out of the 'parameters' value
    NSData *httpBodyData = [someString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [mutableRequest setHTTPBody:httpBodyData];

    return mutableRequest;
}
```

You could take a look inside the implementation of `AFJSONRequestSerializer` for an example of setting custom HTTP body content.

Answer (score 4):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:url parameters:jsonObject success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //success
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //fail
}];
```

This is the best and most concise way that I have found.

Comment: This is much simpler than the other approaches. However strange thing is, this doesn't seem to work with GET ...

Comment: @Hampotato Generally you shouldn't have a body in your get request. It's possible but non standard.

Comment: Yeah I figured. Thanks tdeegan!

Comment: This is not woking for body.

Answer (score 0):

May be we can use the NSMutableURLRequest, here is the code :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:yourURLString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *contentJSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:[contentJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```