# Unable to set HTTP body on AFNetworking POST request

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, nsurlrequest, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to do a POST request with a http body using AFNetworking. I used [this post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712612/how-to-set-http-request-body-using-afnetworks-afhttprequestoperationmanager) answer

```
  NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my-url"];
  NSString *parameterData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"request_type=get_story_nids&story_type=%@&story_number=%@", section, count];

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [request setHTTPBody:[parameterData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
  [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
  [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
  AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id result) {
              completionBlock(nids,nil);  
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            completionBlock(nil, error);
        }];
```

I put breakpoints in the completion blocks of op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess and it doesn't even hit it.

If it helps, doing

```
NSMutableData* result = [[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request   returningResponse:&response error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

works and gives me the right data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

add break point to  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]; and check do you get proper url if you get url null then try following code

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"url = %@",url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to add your operation to a operation queue. You can find an example here: http://samwize.com/2013/03/02/queue-http-operations-with-afnetworking/

```
// Add the operation to a queue
// It will start once added
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[operationQueue addOperation:op];
```

You can also add https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger to log all operations AFNetworking is dealing with.