# How to decode string with Base64 in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, base64

I am getting encoded string.string contains '=' sign at last. I am trying to decode it,using Base64
but its not decode properly.Here is my code:

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:string options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"decodedString %@", decodedString);
```

but, decodedString is nil.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try passing `NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters` to the `options` parameter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020307/how-to-decode-convert-a-base64-string-to-nsdata

Comment: There are online base64 encoder/decoder available.. try to verify your encoded base 64 string i.e., whether string is valid base64 encoded string or not?

Comment: Yes,it is valid base64 encoded string.

Comment: Is `decodedData` already nil or not? If `decodedData` is not nil but `decodedString` is nil, then the data does not contain a valid UTF-8 string. - You should show an example Base64 string that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only logical explanation I can see is that the string that you are decoding is empty because that is the correct way to decode a base64 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are encoding it wrong. Try this code, its working fine and tested:

```
NSString *string = @"user3007459=";
NSString *base64EncodedString = [[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64EncodedString options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"decodedString %@", decodedString);
```