# Want to convert 3DES Encrypted NSData to NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, encryption, nsdata, 3des

In my project, I am encrypting some data (string) using the 3DES encryption algorithm. The string I pass to the encryption function returns me a NSData object.

Now I want to convert NSData to NSString, so that I can send that string to server.

So I used this code to convert NSData to NSString

`NSString *stringCreated = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encryptedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];`

But when I print this string, It prints very few characters on the console. I think there are few characters which is making a sequence of "\0" due to which it prints the string upto that character only.

I tried to encode the data with `NSUTF8StringEncoding` but it returns me (null).

I want to send the complete string to the server, what to do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work since encrypted string is binary data. Convert it to Base64, if you need to use textual representation.

Here is described convertion of NSData to NSString : [Converting NSData to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197362/converting-nsdata-to-base64)

Comment: Is there any other approach I can follow in order to send the encrypted data to SOAP Webservice, other than the Base64 String?

Comment: Sending the hexadecimal representation is another alternative. Remember that you'll need to convert back on the server side, so don't try to get too creative.

Comment: For short strings hex representation would be better and easier-in-implementation solution, I agree.