# How do I use SKReceiptRefreshRequest to restore a purchase in StoreKit in iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

From all the other answers on stack**overflow**, I have not found the answer to this particular question.

I am using SKReceiptRefreshRequest to restore a purchase. I am using a sandbox account. I have the following code:

```
let request = SKReceiptRefreshRequest()  

request.delegate = self  

request.start()
```

When the result is a call to requestDidFinish of the SKRequestDelegate protocol. The request I get back has nil for its receiptProperties property. How do I interpret that? The documentation ([Refreshing the App Receipt](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW2)) says to check the receipt, but there appears to be nothing to check.

Here is my code when I assume that getting a request back with nil receiptProperties mean that I received back a receipt.

```
extension SettingsTableViewController: SKRequestDelegate {

    func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {

        print("requestDidFinish")

        print("request=", request)

        if let receiptRefreshRequest = request as? SKReceiptRefreshRequest {

            print("receipt properties=", receiptRefreshRequest.receiptProperties as Any)

        }

        if iCloudAvailable() {

            ubiquitousKeyValueStore.set(true, forKey: UbiquitousKeys.iMessageExtension)

            let alertMessage = "iMessage Saved Messages has been restored."

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

            alert.addAction(actionOK)

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }

    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {

        print("requst(_:didFailWithError:)")

        if let receiptRefreshRequest = request as? SKReceiptRefreshRequest {

            print("receipt properties=", receiptRefreshRequest.receiptProperties as Any)

        } else {

            print("request=", request)
        }

        print("error=", error)

        let alertMessage = "There are no purchases to restore."

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)

        let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(actionOK)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Comment: Show your actual code for creating the request and handling the response.

Comment: @rmaddy I just added the code in the post above. I assumed that getting a request back in requestDidFinish with nil for receiptProperties means there is a receipt available.

Comment: Show how you really create the `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` instance. The `init` takes a parameter. And be sure you read the documentation for `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` and its `init`.

Comment: @rmaddy None of the states that make up the receiptProperties seemed to apply, so I didn't use any of the parameters. I used the code just as it says in the documentation I gave a link to in the post.

Comment: @rmaddy Did I get this right? How do I distinguish the receipt for one product from the receipt of another product?

Answer (score 2):

I found this webpage with the answer. Apple's documentation didn't show this where it was needed.

["Restoring non-consumable IAPs in iOS" at upbeat.it](https://www.upbeat.it/restoring-non-consumable-iaps-in-ios/)

```
func validateReceipt() {
    let recURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL!
    let contents = NSData(contentsOf: recURL)
    let receiptData = contents!.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    print(receiptData)
    let requestContents = ["receipt-data" : receiptData]
    print(requestContents)
    let requestData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestContents, options: [])
    print(requestData)
    let serverURL = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt" // TODO:change this in production with https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
    let url = NSURL(string: serverURL)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = requestData
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            self.notifyReceiptResult(false)
            return
        }
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:[]) as? [String: Any]
            if let receipt = json?["receipt"] as? [String: AnyObject],
                let inApp = receipt["in_app"] as? [AnyObject] {
                print(inApp)
                if (inApp.count > 0) {
                    self.notifyReceiptResult(true)
                } else {
                    self.notifyReceiptResult(false)
                }
            }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
            self.notifyReceiptResult(false)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: It looks like this stack**overflow** post answers the question too.

[How to get iOS appStoreReceiptURL into Base 64 Encoded String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924411/how-to-get-ios-appstorereceipturl-into-base-64-encoded-string)

Comment: That’s great but a link is not an answer.