# Check auto-renewable subscription expire date from validate receipt

Tags: objective-c, ios7, in-app-purchase

I am calling receipt validation method in app delegate to check the renewable process. Its working fine in development mode but after releasing from app store its always returning yes, even though user have not purchase the product. Please Suggest what wrong I am doing. In sandbox mode its working fine but after release I found the issue that its always returning true. For validating receipt I am using below code

// Validate the receipt

```
+(BOOL ) getStoreReceipt:(BOOL)sandbox andTrasaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)tractaion{

    NSArray *objects;
    NSArray *keys;
    NSDictionary *dictionary;

    BOOL gotreceipt = false;

    @try {

        NSURL *receiptUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[receiptUrl path]]) {

            NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptUrl];

            NSString *receiptString = [self base64forData:receiptData];
            NSLog(@"receiptString Value---->= %@",receiptString);

            NSString *encReceipt = [receiptData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
            NSLog(@"receiptString Value ======>= %@",encReceipt);
            if (receiptString != nil) {
                NSString *strSharedSecrect = @"MY_Secrect_Key";
                objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:receiptString,strSharedSecrect, nil];
                keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"receipt-data",@"password", nil];
                dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

                NSString *postData = [self getJsonStringFromDictionary:dictionary];
                NSLog(@"postData Value---->= %@",receiptString);
                NSString *urlSting = @"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
               // if (sandbox) urlSting = @"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";

                dictionary = [self getJsonDictionaryWithPostFromUrlString:urlSting andDataString:postData];
                  NSLog(@"dictionary Value for receipt---->= %@",dictionary);
                if ([dictionary objectForKey:@"status"] != nil) {

                    if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"status"] intValue] == 0) {

                        gotreceipt = true;

                    }
                }

            }

        }//623065

    } @catch (NSException * e) {
        gotreceipt = false;
        return NO;
         NSLog(@"NSException---->= %@",e);
    }

    if (!gotreceipt) {
          NSLog(@"Not gotreceipt---->=");
        objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"-1", nil];
        keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"status", nil];
        dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
        return NO;
    }else{
        BOOL isPurchased = [self PurchasedSubscriptionStatues:dictionary];
         return isPurchased;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Checking if pending for renewable is there or not...

```
+(BOOL)PurchasedSubscriptionStatues:(NSDictionary *)transactionReceipt
{
    if ([[transactionReceipt allKeys] containsObject:@"pending_renewal_info"]) {

        NSArray *arrData = [transactionReceipt objectForKey:@"pending_renewal_info"];
        NSDictionary *dicPendinRenew = [arrData objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([[dicPendinRenew allKeys] containsObject:@"expiration_intent"] || [[dicPendinRenew objectForKey:@"auto_renew_status"] integerValue]==0) {
            return NO;
        }else if ([[dicPendinRenew objectForKey:@"auto_renew_status"] integerValue]==1) {

            return YES;
        }else{
           return NO;
        }
    }else{
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Convert String To Dictionary

```
+(NSString *)getJsonStringFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dicVal
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dicVal options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *postString = @"";
    if (! postData) {
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
        return nil;
    }
    else { postString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        return postString;
    }
}
Convert  Dictionary to string
+(NSDictionary *) getJsonDictionaryWithPostFromUrlString:(NSString *)urlString andDataString:(NSString *)dataString {
    NSString *jsonString = [self getStringWithPostFromUrlString:urlString andDataString:dataString];
    NSLog(@"getJsonDictionaryWithPostFromUrlString-->%@", jsonString); // see what the response looks like
    return [self getDictionaryFromJsonString:jsonString];
}


+ (NSDictionary *) getDictionaryFromJsonString:(NSString *)jsonstring {
    NSError *jsonError;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *) [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&jsonError];
    if (jsonError) {
        dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

//Request for post method to get the recipt

```
+ (NSString *) getStringWithPostFromUrlString:(NSString *)urlString andDataString:(NSString *)dataString {
    NSString *s = @"";
    @try {
        NSData *postdata = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postlength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postdata length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setTimeoutInterval:60];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postlength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postdata];
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        if (data != nil) {
            s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        s = @"";
    }
    return s;
}


// from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197362/converting-nsdata-to-base64
+ (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData {
    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];
    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;
    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }
        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}


------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your questions format is terrible; please fix it

Answer (score 0):

I think your `PurchasedSubscriptionStatues` method has an error: if the receipt does not contain `pending_renewal_info` key, it returns `YES`. Try creating a new sandbox user and see if the receipt contains this key, if not - then this method should return `NO` in such case.

Also, you can try using some library that can manage InApp purchases, like [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore), to ease on the receipt verification.