# Get NSString/NSData object from hardcoded bytes saved as NSString object in webservice response

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsdata

I am working with the iPhone SDK and I have to process a webservice response I receive from an external service.

1. The response data consists of an XML string that was UTF8-encoded to a byte array.
2. This byte array is converted to string
3. This string is put into a XML wrapper element
4. The wrapper is returned via an HTTP response

Therefore I need to know how to convert the response data back to the XML string it used to be. Unfortunately, I cannot change the way my response is created, so I have to deal with it somehow.

Example of the raw data I get from the webservice:

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body><ExportBytesResponse xmlns="http://knowledgepark-ag.com/webservices/">
    <ExportBytesResult>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</ExportBytesResult>
</ExportBytesResponse></s:Body>
```

How do I get back my old xml string representation hidden inside these raw bytes?

Any help is highly appreciated, I feel just stupid right now for not being able to come up with a solution.

Best Regards,
David

Comment: Is your data in the ExportBytesResult node, or are you asking how to turn that whole thing back into XML?

Comment: I want to convert the raw data inside my <ExportBytesResult> node back to its original XML representation.

This has to work somehow with [NSString stringWithBytes ...] but I could not get it to work with something like that until now.

Comment: Ah right. ExportBytesResult's contents are Base64 encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExportBytesResponse is Base64 encoded, so you must first decode that node using [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk).

That will give you an NSString containing the XML. Then you can use [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse your data.

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. Windows Azure AppFabric apparently encodes the byte array in the response with Base64.