# Problem in encoding and decoding the string in Iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

HI Guys,

```
   Here I am having a problem In encoding/decoding the strings.

Actually I had a string which I am encoding it using the base64.which was working fine.
And now I need to decode the string that was encoded before and want to print it.
I code I written as:

I imported the base64.h and base64.m files into my application which contains the methods as:

+ (NSData *) dataWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *) string;
- (id) initWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *) string;
- (NSString *) base64EncodingWithLineLength:(unsigned int) lineLength;

And the code in my view controller where I encode the String is:

- (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
    // Custom initialization

  userName = @"Sekhar";
  password = @"Bethalam";
    }
    return self;
    }

-(void)reloadView
{
 NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",userName,password];
 NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [authData base64EncodingWithLineLength:30]];
 NSLog(authValue);
 //const char *str = authValue;
 //NSString *decStr = [StringEncryption DecryptString:authValue];
 //NSLog(decStr);

 //NSData *decodeData = [NSData decode:authValue];
 //NSString *decStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",decodeData];
 //NSStr
 //NSLog(decStr);
}

   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
     [self reloadView];
    }
```

and now I want to decode the String that I encoded.

But I dont know How to do that.can anyone suggest me with code how to get it.

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.
Thank you,
Monish.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk

Comment: I used the reference of the link u had posted but Im getting the output when I decode the text as:
<50000053 60005365 4053656b 6b656b68 656b6861 6b686172 3861723a 41723a42 723a4265 76426574 62657468 65746861 6c68616c 68616c61 616c616d>

Comment: Guys Please Give me a quick solution.

Comment: Cross post: http://efreedom.com/Question/1-2432680/Problem-Encoding-Decoding-String-iPhone-Sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Base64DecodeLookup method in the Base64 class. For a solid description on how to use that for the mac and the iphone try checking out this article.
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html

Cheers