# File upload in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iphone application which needs to upload some image files to server.The images needs to be uploaded as binary data.I converted the image to NSData using 
[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

But i dont know how to convert this NSData to Binary data.Looking for a solution

Thanks,

Comment: NSData is already a binary data. What do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try base64 encoding of the binary data. Convert your NSData object to base 64 using QSStrings. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Read the How-to-use section http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use There are some examples of sending files and NSData