# UIImage to base64 String Encoding

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to convert `UIimage` to base64 encoded string? I couldn't find any examples or codes with detailed regarding.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios

Answer (score 56):

I wonder why didn't you find your question because it's a very old question & can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk).

Anyways, 
You need to first add `NSData` categories to your project which are available from here -

[header](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine/blob/master/NSData%2BBase64.h) and [implementation](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine/blob/master/NSData%2BBase64.m)
Then convert your `UIImage` object into `NSData` the following way:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

And then apply **Base64** encoding to convert it into a `base64` encoded string:

```
NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64Encoding];
```

Comment: http://svn.cocoasourcecode.com/MGTwitterEngine/MGTwitterEngineGlobalHeader.h -- However it should not be required and can be removed from header

Comment: anyreason that why it takes some time to covert  ??

Answer (score 47):

**There are changes in iOS 7 that allow this to be done without using any external categories to support Base64 encoding/decoding.**

You could just write it directly using:

```
- (NSString *)base64String {
    return [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}
```

Comment: Note that these methods have been introduced with iOS 7 but `base64Encoding` has been made available back to iOS 4. So unless you still support iOS 2 or 3 you can use `base64Encoding` or the one @Abizern mentions without any external frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the back port.

Comment: I had better luck when passing options of `0` instead of `NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength`. That way it does not insert any line breaks, and is usable in a `data:` URI in UIWebView.

Comment: @TalkLittle try using `kNilOptions`. Same thing but more readable

Comment: NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed

Answer (score 9):

You can follow below code

```
-(NSString *)imageToNSString:(UIImage *)image
{
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    return [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}

-(UIImage *)stringToUIImage:(NSString *)string
{
 NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:string
                                                     options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
    return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
@implementation UIImage (Extended)

- (NSString *)base64String {
    NSData * data = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self) base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why don't use base64EncodedStringWithOptions directly?

Comment: So the code doesn't look like spagety :) a good habbit is to avoid 3 statements in each other like [Me doSmthh:[[Something execute:@"..."] someTypeOfValue]];

Answer (score 3):

NSData (Base64) has changed slightly since the last reply in this thread.

you should now use:

```
NSData *base64EncodedImage = [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.8) base64EncodingWithLineLength:0];
```

Comment: base64EncodingWithLineLength returns NSData

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

I use **base64EncodedString()** to convert **Data()** object to base64 string

To convert image to base64 string

```
    var sample = UIImage(named: "image_logo")
    let imageData:Data =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(sample!)!
    let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString()
```

Answer (score 0):

when converting to image to base64 in ios the new line “\n” from base64 encoded strings :

use this code :

```
 UIImage* orginalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];



        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:isRowIndex inSection:isSectionIndex] ;

        UITableViewCell *cell = [jobstable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        UIImageView *tableIMAGE=(UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:19];

        tableIMAGE.image=orginalImage;



imageStris = [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tableIMAGE.image,1)base64Encoding];

answersARRAY[indexPath.row] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-1,%@,%@",answersARRAY[indexPath.row],imageStris];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```