# Convert between UIImage and Base64 string

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, base64, nsdata

Does anyone know how to convert a `UIImage` to a Base64 string, and then reverse it?

I have the below code; the original image before encoding is good, but I only get a blank image after I encode and decode it.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage);

NSString *b64EncStr = [self encode: imageData];

NSString *base64String = [self encodeBase64:imageData];
```

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64/

Answer (score 616, accepted):

### Swift

**First we need to have image's NSData**

```
//Use image name from bundle to create NSData
let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"imageNameHere")!
//Now use image to create into NSData format
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

//OR next possibility

//Use image's path to create NSData
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string : "urlHere")!
//Now use image to create into NSData format
let imageData:NSData = NSData.init(contentsOfURL: url)!
```

**Swift 2.0 > Encoding**

```
let strBase64:String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

**Swift 2.0 > Decoding**

```
let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: strBase64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)!
```

**Swift 3.0 > Decoding**

```
let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: strBase64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
```

**Encoding** :

```
let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
print(strBase64)
```

**Decoding** :

```
let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: strBase64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
let decodedimage:UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)!
print(decodedimage)
yourImageView.image = decodedimage
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: strBase64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
yourImageView.image = decodedimage
```

---

### Objective-C

### iOS7 > version

You can use `NSData's` `base64EncodedStringWithOptions`

**Encoding** :

```
- (NSString *)encodeToBase64String:(UIImage *)image {
 return [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}
```

**Decoding** :

```
- (UIImage *)decodeBase64ToImage:(NSString *)strEncodeData {
  NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:strEncodeData options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
  return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

---

### iOS 6.1 and < version

**First Option** : Use [this](http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-base64-encode-decode.php) link to `encode` and `decode` image

Add [Base64](http://www.imthi.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/base64.zip) class in your `project`.

**Encoding** :

```
 NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0f);
 NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];
```

**Decoding** :

```
 NSData* data = [Base64 decode:strEncoded ];;
 image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

**Another Option**: Use [QSUtilities](https://github.com/mikeho/QSUtilities/blob/master/QSStrings.h) for `encoding` and `decoding`

---

Comment: Thanks, but how I can encode the image with that link? I didn't see a method that takes in NSData. There's only one that decodes the string. Thanks!

Comment: add base64 class in your project and use its methods

Comment: @Safecase I wasn't the person that voted you down, but possibly the double post is the offence?

Comment: It is not that but i wanted to give right answer to the question

Comment: `Base64` Class sleeps forever, I always force quite xcode if I use this even after making the image quality to 0.001f

Comment: @shebelaw: are you using ARC? if so, remove the `autoRelease` call in `Base64.m`.

Comment: @Prince: Bit late in the day, I know, but thanks for this. saved me a major headache.

Comment: In the first option, `[Base64 initialize]` should not be called. This gets called automatically upon class initialization: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize

Comment: This no longer works: `var url:NSURL = NSURL(string : "urlHere")!
var imageData:NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url, options: nil, error: nil)`

Use `var imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOfMappedFile: "urlHere")` instead.

Comment: EDIT: `var imageData:NSData = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath("urlHere")`

Comment: NSData(contentsOfURL: url, options: nil, error: nil) is what you should use now for Swift

Comment: @E. Spiroux : Your suggestion has been added in answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Would also be helpful to add @quemeful suggestion as the current code doesn't compile in Swift 2.x

Comment: @Crashalot : Have done changes please let me know if there is any other changes

Comment: when i do the  encoding , it takes some time ,  is this normal or is there anyway that i can avoid this ??

Comment: wish there was a concrete example on how to post multipart form with png using alamofire.

Comment: Important note: make sure your base64 string doesn't include the prefix required on a browser to display, e.g. `data:image/jpeg;base64,`

Comment: @TylerSheaffer I think this is an important message, which should be included in the answer.

Comment: For new versions of swift, this :

`//Now use image to create into NSData format
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!`

have to be replaced by : 
`let imageData = UIImage.pngData(image!)`

Comment: I get a nil value upon conversion, can't understand where it is going wrong

Answer (score 88):

## Swift 5

**Encoding**

```
func convertImageToBase64String (img: UIImage) -> String {
    return img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.base64EncodedString() ?? ""
}
```

**Decoding**

```
func convertBase64StringToImage (imageBase64String:String) -> UIImage {
    let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: imageBase64String)
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    return image!
}
```

> Note: Tested in xcode 10.2

## Swift 4

**Encoding**

```
func convertImageToBase64String (img: UIImage) -> String {
    let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.50)! as NSData //UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
    let imgString = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .init(rawValue: 0))
    return imgString
}
```

**Decoding**

```
func convertBase64StringToImage (imageBase64String:String) -> UIImage {
    let imageData = Data.init(base64Encoded: imageBase64String, options: .init(rawValue: 0))
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    return image
}
```

> Note: Tested in xcode 9.4.1

Comment: Thank you for comment on my answer, Can you please up vote my answer, this is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 42):

**Swift 4.2 Extension method**

```
extension UIImage {
    func toBase64() -> String? {
        guard let imageData = self.pngData() else { return nil }
        return imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
    }
}
```

**XCode 9.1 and Swift 4.0**

```
//
// Convert UIImage to a base64 representation
//
class func convertImageToBase64(image: UIImage) -> String {
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
    return imageData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
}

//
// Convert a base64 representation to a UIImage
//
class func convertBase64ToImage(imageString: String) -> UIImage {
    let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: imageString, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
    return UIImage(data: imageData)!
}
```

Comment: This is not good. You shouldn't force unwrap image, as it would result in crashing of app if it fails to get image from data. You should unwrap last line like this "return UIImage(data: imageData) ?? UIImage()"

Comment: Force unwrap is not good practice, I propose:

func convertBase64StringToImage(imageBase64String:String) -> UIImage? {
        guard let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: imageBase64String) else { return nil }
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        return image
    }

Answer (score 20):

**SWIFT 3.0, XCODE 8.0**

Replace String with your URL. and testImage is an outlet of ImageView

```
// Put Your Image URL
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string : "http://.jpg")!
// It Will turn Into Data
let imageData : NSData = NSData.init(contentsOf: url as URL)!
// Data Will Encode into Base64
let str64 = imageData.base64EncodedData(options: .lineLength64Characters)
// Now Base64 will Decode Here
let data: NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: str64 , options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
// turn  Decoded String into Data
let dataImage = UIImage(data: data as Data)
// pass the data image to image View.:)
testImage.image = dataImage
```

Hope It Helps Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Swift iOS8

```
// prgm mark ---- 

// convert images into base64 and keep them into string

func convertImageToBase64(image: UIImage) -> String {

    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)

    return base64String

}// end convertImageToBase64


// prgm mark ----

// convert images into base64 and keep them into string

func convertBase64ToImage(base64String: String) -> UIImage {

    let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0) )

    var decodedimage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)

    return decodedimage!

}// end convertBase64ToImage
```

Answer (score 8):

```
@implementation UIImage (Extended)

- (NSString *)base64String {
    NSData * data = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self) base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]];
}

@end
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Love it!

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3.0**

To convert image to base64 string

**Tested in playground**

```
    var logo = UIImage(named: "image_logo")
    let imageData:Data =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(logo)
    let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString()
    print(base64String)
```

Answer (score 7):

In swift 2.0 use this extension (credit to Jonas Franz)

```
extension UIImage{
  func toBase64() -> String{
    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)!
    return imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For the Base64 code like:

> "data:image/jpg;base64,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"

Use Swift5.0 code like:

```
func imageFromBase64(_ base64: String) -> UIImage? {
    if let url = URL(string: base64), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        return UIImage(data: data)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Can someone point where this behavior is documented?

Comment: This is not correct. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51394491/1294452 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/47610733/1294452 below

Comment: @nodebase This solution is working for me. Why this is not correct? Can you provide more context. I need to convert image of type `"data:image/jpg;base64,iV...` And none of the below solution is not working for this case.

Answer (score 5):

## In Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.0

### Encoding :

```
let userImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "Your-Image_name")!
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(userImage)! as NSData
let dataImage = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

### Decoding :

```
let imageData = dataImage
let dataDecode:NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: imageData!, options:.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
let avatarImage:UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecode as Data)!
yourImageView.image = avatarImage
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift-Extension:

```
extension UIImage{
     func toBase64() -> String{
          var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)
          return imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
     }
}
```

Comment: For Swift 2.2, .allZeros didn't compile.  So I used return imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

Comment: Use Encoding64CharacterLineLength instead of allZero

Comment: im using switft3, unable to convert to send to server:
`let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ImageView.image!);
let strBase64:String = imageData!.base64EncodedString()`

Comment: @Cmag I know your comment is 2 years old but did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @ZUNJAE am afraid i dont recall how i fixed it, dont have access to the solution any more

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**

```
enum ImageFormat {
    case png
    case jpeg(CGFloat)
}

extension UIImage {
    func base64(format: ImageFormat) -> String? {
        var imageData: Data?

        switch format {
        case .png: imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)
        case .jpeg(let compression): imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, compression)
        }

        return imageData?.base64EncodedString()
    }
}

extension String {
    func imageFromBase64() -> UIImage? {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) else { return nil }

        return UIImage(data: data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5.**

```
class ImageConverter {

    func base64ToImage(_ base64String: String) -> UIImage? {
        guard let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(data: imageData)
    }

    func imageToBase64(_ image: UIImage) -> String? {
        return image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.base64EncodedString()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried all the solutions, none worked for me (using Swift 4), this is the solution that worked for me, if anyone in future faces the same problem.

```
let temp = base64String.components(separatedBy: ",")
let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: temp[1], options: 
 .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)

yourImage.image = decodedimage
```

Comment: I also tried for many solutions , This solution saves my next many hours

Comment: I was trying all the solutions and finally you saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift version - create base64 for image**

In my opinion Implicitly Unwrapped Optional in case of `UIImagePNGRepresenatation()` is not safe, so I recommend to use extension like below:

```
extension UIImage {

    func toBase64() -> String? {
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)
        return imageData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a very good to understand do you pass prefix as **Tyler Sheaffer** told.
But for some reason you may need this prefix that describe the mime-type in the beginning of the base64 string, so I suggest this piece of code to pass some options before encoding (**Swift 5**):

```
extension UIImage {

    enum Format: String {
        case png = "png"
        case jpeg = "jpeg"
    }

    func toBase64(type: Format = .jpeg, quality: CGFloat = 1, addMimePrefix: Bool = false) -> String? {
        let imageData: Data?
        switch type {
        case .jpeg: imageData = jpegData(compressionQuality: quality)
        case .png:  imageData = pngData()
        }
        guard let data = imageData else { return nil }

        let base64 = data.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)

        var result = base64
        if addMimePrefix {
            let prefix = "data:image/\(type.rawValue);base64,"
            result = prefix + base64
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Decoding using convenience initialiser - Swift 5

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(base64String: String) {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) else { return nil }
        self.init(data: data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
See my class -  AppExtension.swift


// MARK: - UIImage (Base64 Encoding)

public enum ImageFormat {
    case PNG
    case JPEG(CGFloat)
}

extension UIImage {

    public func base64(format: ImageFormat) -> String {
        var imageData: NSData
        switch format {
        case .PNG: imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)
        case .JPEG(let compression): imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, compression)
        }
        return imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 3.0**

```
func decodeBase64(toImage strEncodeData: String) -> UIImage {

    let dataDecoded  = NSData(base64Encoded: strEncodeData, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
    let image = UIImage(data: dataDecoded as Data)
    return image!

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2 | Xcode 10

```
extension UIImage {

    /// EZSE: Returns base64 string
    public var base64: String {
        return self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)!.base64EncodedString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5, Xcode 10.**

```html
 let imageData = UIImage(named:"imagename").pngData()?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

print(imageData)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//convert Image to Base64 (Encoding)

let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

print(strBase64)

// convert Base64 to Image (Decoding)

let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: strBase64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!

let decodedimage:UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)!

print(decodedimage)

yourImageView.image = decodedimage
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 7+, Objective-C, here's how to make the conversion starting with an image URL:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.groove.thumbnailURL];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

NSString *base64String = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.0

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 1)

    let base64String = (imageData! as Data).base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    print(base64String)
```