# objective c - ios base64 image string decoding

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, ios6, base64

I want to decode a correct `base64` string image (I can print out as html `<img src=... />`) and visualize in a `UIImageView` .

```
[Base64 initialize];
NSData *data = [Base64 decode:img];
cell.image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

I tried [this](http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-base64-encode-decode.php) solution, but seem don't work on ios6 (I can't see the image given that code. Of course I imported the `Base64.h` file).

my base64 encoded image:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABOCAYAAAHAyqHQAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAIGNIUk0AAG2YAABzjgAA47MAAIZgAAB5jQAAz5oAADF1AAAdKk1oIhIAADlCSURBVHjaPMoxSwJhAAbg987vQkXQEqELNR1sMZ2zhqbMf+Bklw3nEBWi0CKJbo0OiZttQsIJXU4NLgoNLjpc+QVCeA4mYgmBCnkNYsOzPawsy1ipVqsQBAFXF5d7qVQKlNJ/7GQywUq9Xj/07HjgcrleIpEIut3uP3bX68VKr9c7abfaB/l8XpMkCYQQEI4D4Tiwg8EnVn6nM10ykWhIFYlxu932p0f5xmQwwmQwgrU77LCYzbCYzYgnk6eh45Cm9vvo99T9eDye5XkePM+DBYDXzhuK90UsoCGdzTBOpxObW/zDdD7DWTSKzjtdRgCABhBC4Pf5tofDIZrN5rmiKNARAgDLyDAMKKVQVRWtVuujUCjAZrPdNRoNLBYLaJoGdjQaQa/Xr4+/v9q1Wi1DKb2OxWIbwWAQ5XJ5Tta450qlAtbhcMBqtY5LpZI/EAikBUG4DYfDiiiKA47jfnK53JEoivgDAAD//3TRPUsCYQAH8P9dlvWgq1NQURxqLzhGUxAiDoLg0ni9XZPQFwhNuHqewWwObsrAwSC1G0Mk0JYTJ4fqxgoHucGGPI+eJq2Qfl/hJ/6eMQwDezu7eH99+7MyNkMp9YRCodhVPo9IJML/nclkMh/nuVw5HA5D0zRhuDI2IwgC0ifpzUajDuVQ4cMVzwyB6HJNjGbO1NN1xtg1owx3pcr0cGXK7YZoNJuo1Wr4Ase+cvDo9/tnV9ZWUaqU+592H71eDwNn8DPDOUehUIDP57tIJpOLnU5nq91uj+JEy7KWOefQdR1erxfVavVIVVUzHo/fm6YJzjkIIRBbrdbx3MK8VCwWXwKBwKQkSTeMMXS7Xdi2rdyWSxvRaDQmplKpbcdxnnRdX9I07YEQYlFK5Ww2+5xIJC5lWa4Hg8HKNwAAAP//bNNPSFMBHAfw73vzTZ2XDZ/09DUdgkiLKR5W4Q7PuUaBo1Yrln96U8YTog566OAxCC+12UWGRNncFqYHDxvyZh3XElMKttA5wmSKSI5Q8oHszdfRHPvB5/g7fPn9vucuU9qfZDJJm81msUnfqPhf+i6vfl2tGBsbMy0uLlbFYjGUQ2YyGZQTDAZnaZo+uMiyN/V6fUyW5R/hcHhkbW0tVVNTQ1IUVdHc3IxSZJO+EeWkv313+3w+1NI0cHqqeffmbXYpHn/i9XrB1jdIy8kvVZ+WPqIU+TObRTkjo6MEP/AQ9133YGwzJUKz71sEQTDU1dKYnJx8VFRO//7OH6AUeevuHagq1bjANoCzWmG12WC12dDe0YFIJIJ0Oo3W1ta4JEkaqlJtX1hYgCAIgUHegyHPIIY8g+jv7YOlsxMOh+PscUiSRCKRQHBmBgoBKATg7n2Ajc3MK51OlzQYDNLx8fFqbR19W1yKo1CUUSjKEAQBsiyDVKnOqv//ZDY2EI1GodVqoVarUV1d/Wx+fh7T09M4Ojq6wbLs593dXYRCIUSjURAEcW6fHB4efk3TNDYzm9jf3+8nCGKZ53k4nc5fXV1dWF9ffy5JUtbtdqvsdvusKIoHDMPA4/FgampKYRjmQy6X09Uz9Zibm3tKhsNhwWg0otvWDfPVK5G+gf5rW1tbRCAQMPA8j56ensccx7Xk8/miKIqgKAq5XI7w+/0YHx8nuq/b3Kb2tj8FuYBUKvXiXGSNRgOapnFycqIcHh7C5XLBZDKB4zhMTExgZ2cHFosFTqdTcTgc2Nvbu6TVarGysoLt7W0AwD9CyzWmzTKK4/++lEtNoJP7RUi5Sxg4qZRI+cLsRMFgIgbHZZgNV6cTBELUtAPTBqoIMgIRCFsqHzBDybjoqoEgkpg0uhowpbztCgQC7H1bAi33AlpePwAba2Ge5Pfl+XBynuec88tz6qaIxWKIxWLcun0bfXd7WZcKCrOmp6ad3ObkOjwlZDIZvlAomI6Ojk6hUDha91XdNyaTye2pCY/L8zgqlcre1NQE1U/3WCkpKe+azeat8vLy64WFhbttbW11bDYbJ0HQNA1H1Gr1eY1G45KZmQmxWIyhoaGJ/f19T6PR+HxPTw/LYDBcDQ8PR1hYmBPEBZEIjuTk5IzodDpQFIWHNLVO0/TZ7u7uqeeCQww7OztQKpXeC4uLoGjaCcL4wAhHvq5vUF29fGXPx8cHNTU1Xq4uLthcXw/w8fNFf38/Pvrw+jQ5oQsnJ3RwhOCeOQNHJFJpVkhIyG8BAQHg8/mov9kYcDE/n6XRaNDT08Osr69HCgSCWYFAAEeIMY0Gjvw+OooahSIj48Kry5998mlTUFDQ0s7eLp7x4AD7DJJe4v+o+uVnnAQRGROD8yKRE15eXggMDLSNj49/3NjYeJYkSajV6sLc3Nz4psabb753pRjH+eD9awfG3tzahFY3gc7OTjAM8wQVFRWhMpmMJZfLdX5+frIXXjzXtbGxQdrtdhzBMAyKiopwt68Xbm5ujwf7cFweqUv/wID7f2mwsbWJ4eFhaLXaz8fGxvCQph6pCwQLIyMjcHd3f2yb07bE5cBvz87Nzb2Snp4OuVwOiqJqD89PDaeER9cdGBi4k5SUJORyub/K5fI3FArFt0KhUOrr63uOJMlgkiSh1Wr/P+G/e/+gubkZZWVleTMzMy7z8/OS4uLie9HR0ZcHBwdzAwMDZ0JDQ6na2lpER0Q6J3R1dcXy8nLCUWUsFgvb29sgSRJ9fX0D9fX1CpvNBpPJhOTk5B+Gh4c3JicnD9+NBYIgDj5zxEFthEql+rKoqGjC09NTSdN0hsViQUJCwjtsNhsikehWXV1diVQqBZvNNrS2tu4sLS0xVVVVq9XV1bhRfQO9vb139Hp9o0QiYSQSCUEYjcb8kpKSru0dm9frWZnqqJhocLnc7wG85u3t/XdcXNyf7e3tYVarld3Q0OCxtraGlpaWiI6Oju8kUiku5ufl8SLCXdPS0v4oKyuzEqmpqWFcLrcwOzv7bbPZvLG4uAiTyUTQND04OTnZZjab7+/u7s4HBwfHcjgcdHd3E1ar1eLh4XFpYWEBq6uryMrKKklMTHxZKBRyn2hKcnIyeDweKIqqKSgoYFJSUvL1en27zWZDZWWl3WKxQKlUMnw+H/7+/pK4uDhERkae3GW73Q6SJGEwGJCTkyOZnZ1FfHx8V2lp6TUOh4OpqSnweDxERUVhZWUFIpGoRq/Xv7W1tYXY2FgwDAMA+I8T849p+szj+PtbWmilULG0UFNGKT8KeICIKZJtYMbwB9skYQjGkqjnQcblNJ7hxp2rEVQiN8aUqXhW8IBF4ZzHcgGLiOGHoNPqOFjFIhRERKlUpb/gW/m2/d4fu3HLTVy3J3n9/bzz5Hk+7/f7WdRTXpfK8vPzodFocOLECRQVFSnEYjEtlYTQAQIhvUaeSH9a9lduyYFiqM6ooFQqodfrMTIy8qtgEASBX4KHhwcePXp0XigUor+//+3g4ODG/fv3h5lMJjQ3NxNZWVmEUCi0pb/3HrjeXPT29rYlJibSGzdunOBwOFjMiha1qMU871XY7XYoFAp627ZtOyoqKuDr69sjCgh0/iZ6xWhRUdHv9Xr9whtraWmGWCzG3NychM1mg6KooJSUFLqhoSFzamoKT548cQsGRVFwFwCRN27cICIjI1/m5ORALpfjn183wfj8GRoaGj5WKpV0fX09XVdXRw8ODp7lcDjg8XiyxsZGor29nZDL5RWdnZ1N3d3d6OzsdAvGqpXxcJfJiUfDyUlv0tsUuUaFQmERCARwOp3rlUrlU8vzFxLC6YLz5Tx82JzZrMwPf+vt7Y2dO3diYmICl9WtCA2RXlDu+wSy8AhER0a5BaO2thbu8uLFC56HBwMBAQGTpaWlvgaDARFh4W0ZH2wKSHk39aiLQZiOHf+CyFZs5c6Scz5Xrlx54+HDh29fvXpVyhf4v1VXV3crKyuLHhgYwJ07d9yCIZVI4C6BQuHMwcOHlmRmZsaz2Wz/8bEHWL16NWiaRkSUrPx0tcrPm+cDkiRhtVqtUql0QhYh60lYlbBsv3J/zzw1j/LycsLf3x8/tNKfgxEcEgJ3eUMigSRESkqkUs/QEKmpt7f3cn5+Pn3+/Hl6ampqrfqSGrO2Wfx7oB8dHZ2wmi14abeHBonFd1rVauLQ4cOECzS8fbhuwRf4gyENC4Xx+TPcu6/DU+M0goKCIBAIFsXHxwd8Pn9epVI5tm7duqG4uJigKMoBGs7p6WmW0WjkDQ0N6b799s7DwsJCWqVSnWxpaWE4nU68+04q1ianLMqGdeuRuvYdmM1mrFixApWVlf+b/AQI0DSN/u8GUFZWho6ODuj1+oWJ/v/phMViwW63w4vthbKyMlZ8fPyFoqIiSi6Xmzdt2hR1pro6+NPyckImk20gCMLFYrFemVj6+vrQ3t6Oubk5bN++Hff1w2D+92PntRGJyWRienoa9V9+uZDDfpzHPtyche/uamG12TDvoKBWqwMbGhrix8fHk1taWsLKysqY94fvIzFpDZ4YptB8qWUhq/04s506dQqLiX+twNctJpOJc+fOVaxatUrA5XIhEolCRSLROovFMtrV1XVNKpX2Jycnp6WlpcFiscDlclWy2WzWr9nrZwUO6XRYwuEs3EE/Pz/Ex8fj5s2ba9ra2ozV1dV/J0lyNCYm5l98Pj8xIiJic3R09Bo/P7/WgoKCEzab7em6devqCIKgzGYzzGYzLBYLRkdHQc7O/qRj/2KBBEHAbDKjrq4Oe/fuhVarBUmSaGpqevPo0aMeMzMzR8bHx1FfX2+Wy+XtQ0NDXz1+/Pgui8VCQkLCH2ZmZj6zWq19MpkMg4ODaGxsxJ49e3Dv3j2AduMEKYoilEolHR4eHqTT6fK6urrg7e3daDAYwrVaLRdAH0mSiImJwbNnz/S3b99+v6+vD/v27UNcXJyjtrb2QUhICAYHB2m9Xo8dO3Z4j4yMUBqN5pbD4fiMy+WWq1Qq2m63g8PhBGm12u7Q0NCvdDrdn62zNvB4vPbq6uomkiQRHBysmpiYQFVVlfn06dMbRCJRD+PYsWOfJCUlfe3h4fGIzWafyVUoQIMmQ8PDZu/pdJTT5XSZzCbcvXv3IwaDcfXkyZPNQqEQlZWV2LJlS252dvZMTU3NP8Ri8eWMjAw4nU6XVCrVt7a2VqWmpn48Pj4OJpOJsbExHDlypL2kpGS9QqHYrNFo/lLx+edgerKsJQdLMrNzcl4yWSyzSCTCrl27eE6n06Ojo+MtxoEDBw4vX748UyKRwGg0ggawMT19x7Jly57s2r3r5e/y8lb7+PrC09Pzb3l5eR+VlpYSRqMRPT09iIqKOldVVcVNS0vL2b1798br16+jra2NVCgUUU1NTXV8Pt+VkJCA0tJSIioqCsXFxZHDw8P2oaEhHD9+nKdUKpGenp45otfjm5vfeIWFh/0pKCgIBoMBBoPhUkZGBsH4oSzNzc3B4XCAIAg4nU4QxPdzkSRJUBSFlStXore3t5imadhsNmg0mhKNRhPa09ODyMhI1qFDh8wSiQR2u313d3d39IULF/K8vLxQU1Mzee3aNRQWFj6IjY3F2bNnB6empoRjY2OeGo0Gnp6e3/crhwPz8/NwOBygKGqhwL3ykdA0jaVLlyIiIgJxcXEIDAxEYGCg161bt1ZYrdaDbDYbk5OTq8VicWpubi46OjoOFxQUhKrV6iKtVjsgEomy+/v7/3jx4kXw+fxRgUCQJJPJOsfGxmAymXzNZvPa5ubmJdHR0YiNjUVKSgqsViskEslPjOE/tJp7VFNXvse/+5wQQhIkgBJehRAwCCJ4ERit0oGCVXyU1haKratXqjZY5VZdDLaiVlmoSFup5eHMVaGCYKu2M9ar2AoGbq2V8rKggCAvRR6GIISQF8k594+Kq66pNjpz91qf/3JW9tr7nN/ev8/v99RX/tLSUrz++usoLi7Gpk2b4Ofnh8x9mfjm9Nc4/z/nXEKC57x1q61dcKfnNhITEyGXy9He3v6H+umZtNSThrOzM6RSKQDo/vbffzPL5XI2MTGxLzw8HOfOnRs/efrUw+2jaRpPm1pM8qwTnObv74+GhgZXtVrNI4RQPB4PS5YseSEhIeECy7K2jo6OQV1dXdv4fD4yMjI2d3V14XE2+0k8ddJkZWVFh4WFzbt8+TJHJpM5btmyhQj4gjuxsbF7w8PDfyCEqDgcztjUqVN/mTp16uEvvviCLSsrO9DU1CQJDAzEzJkznwpq8vixBIPBgA0bNijr6upeZFnWJHZyaoqOisapkyclYrF4f09PD8bGxkARCjdv3kRaWppy7dq1H9A0jdzc3K7jx4/TbW1t/38rWFNTs0omk7WGhYVtIoRAJLKHXqeDTqdjqqurj0ilUnz55ZdgGDM0Gg0GBgbcjx8/nkkIgV6vx6FDh4xCoRC2trYWQ1ma/imVSrS1tUWFhYVVLl++HL6+vjBOGJGeno5Nmzahvr4+jhDiTtM0lENDcy5fvpw9PDzcm5KSQhQKBXF3d/9h69at3gBs7O3tYSnUk27Pv2XKlClIT09PjI+PTzObzejs7ASHw4HUxxtFRUUcDoeD7du337l48SJ7+PDh2t27d6dOBn+DwYCSkpIXTp069fLZs2d133zzDSyFmh0UBEuYExwMtVqNvLy8gszMTHA4HNA0zWtraysNCQ2dmAwneoMBmfv3R1pxrCb8fWeAoigolUr09vZix44dOdHR0Zg7b57FUBShYCln//6PtJ9/uPKGQqFgi4qKNtjY2FA8Hs8k5PPBt+KCMUxAwLVG5XcXvVmwmGDMyMnJQUNdPVpuNON4UfEnunEt1PdHLIZqbW2FJXR2dnIPHzmcwYK1CQkJWWtjY5MHQBseHv72kiVLiM5oAGgywRKMflf+/ZE7d+6EEEIgFArxw4+X4efnZ19XV7eip6dH1tvbC0uhrl69Ckuoqqoyzpjh16pWqxEXF3fipZdeAk3TMOj0cH/uOWi0Wnyemzs36+OPRf6zZpEdO3ZAp9M5G41Gb7VaLXlXLj9vNBolZWVlyQ9uKxZBLVq8GJbC4XBGkpKSPMrLy/fPnj0bYicnvLEyAfEJb8Dd06PB28e73k4kAsMw4HK5tUajccDJyamovb29i2XZuRqNBvv27Ut++eWXYSlUe2srLGVJTMxGvV5/Z0F4eHLHrQ730pJSXG9swtA9JZWxJyO4b6Af4zodCCGwtbUFyzDYmrp1PiFEq9Vq8fz8+eeqKqtQU1NjMdTY2BgshWXZugV/fgEzpsvw/XffrTMajStpmraNfSXWLJV4wW6KHby9pWj45Rp2f7QLZpMZikuX3hTyBaqdH+309PD0yL+nUuLekOVQAYGBeBq41tZwcHDgOjs7F548ebL03XffVXO51jh16hQUCgV0Oh20Wi3UajWUSqXTzJkzv9y6dauHbPr02zNmzDjv5eUFS/Dx8cH06dNBeXlLoVQNQSwWQywWw8nJ6bFMmzYNIpEIpSWlE9XV1duFQiF4PB4oikJdXV0mh8OhJ60DRVHYsmXLoIODA0NR1AJvqTdeil6IqMgXn8iLEZGIWRwDAoLBwUFQLMuipaUFfKEANbU1j9RLHgehCOvv77/W1dWVJCQkbGVZBgKB4IPh4WFzYWHhLnt7+85169ZpRCKR9urVqzFWVlaXJ8X642AYBhwOB4SikP1ZNkxm0z/fB3vv3sXdu3fR2Nj4sPTxR2Px4sVZi2NixFlZWVi+fDmmT59eHRER8cW7SXLPt99+W2BnZ1f2pOdpmgZFUcjOzkZycjJYsA8vur+buBNCcPToUfT09KCxsfF3M38rDgeEELi7u4MxMzAajfdYloVQKERERESZo6NjOsuyqsn8gsvlPiKEfqtQtm3bBp1Oh76+PvD5fMvNwujoKI4cOQJrPu8RcWRtw8O4Xgd7Rwc4TpuKlrZWREdHY9asWeDz+aitrYVer0djYyOGhlWgODTy/3oIFYpL/ySPurq70dnZ+ezqgxDyu3picvtZlp0sF3Bpmpa1t7fPb21tDeZyuVMnU9cnrSD5d8ijP9Bza06cOLG9oqLCKicnp83f3//HNWvW1AsEgqHw8PBlarU6h7L0Zf53TtBkMjnX1tbuXLly5dE9e/ZkNDU1Xbxw4cKivXv3oqCgwMPBwWF3VFRUtUgkSlYqlZK+vr5tf2SxnnmLJ7vTJmlpaflTYGCg3VtvvZWekZHxM8MwcHR0vOvo6Gjt7OwMW1vblUKhcN/AwMCQvb29dVNT018lEsneS5cuHW5ubsZvUY+p/7UJcrlctDa3PAzUDg4OCA0NrXZxcVGdOXMmLiwsbM+BAwewcOHCuKtXr/ZIpdKVFy5caHB1dWX7+/udFArFfkdHx6j4+HhERESsc3FxgVQqhVAohLOzMwQ2/H99iwkhKL94EcXFxSgpKQHDMGAYZsjV1bXVbDZf9vX13TY+Ph4QFxf3S1pa2omcnJzvKyoq+M3NzX9Zv379pqGhoWPNzc1Qq39drVdffRXd3d3Q6XSW6EHL3kGK+vX4+umnn9Dd3Q0vLy/I5fImg8GQ3NPTs9fOzu66SqWCr68vKisr0dfXd3/OnDkp33777dqFCxe+4+HhAX9/fzQ1NT3SQ2DZf1MU+Hy+oKOjY5EV10owWXh/tE2AAcMwIITAaDTi4MGD2LhxI6ytrXetXr0aHA4Hg4ODmD9/Pr766it0dXVBqVRCJpMdaWpqwq1bt349th580L/tVZhMaSePwgdyANbW1r8+c+zYsVXXr1//zMPDo+rn6p93G41GDA4OGm7cuAGlUtnp4uLCFYvFCAoKsq2vr2eVSiX0ej3Gxsa2t7W1/e+DJsO/63S6A9HR0eBwOJ1Lly49fODAAVYikQBAkpOTU9yUKVOQk5NzNTQ09P3du3fruVwudDod3d7ezvb393M4HM7mj7Oy8Pnnn79ZVVX1aXl5+arKyspYqqSkpFgikayjaVofHBycYjaZQdM0VVBQsIDH4/G1Wq3RSypFcXFxXkRExE6tVmt75coVXLt2jTswMPDcA1U3Xl5ePlMsFsNkMnHi4+PXRUdH/+P06dNeWq1WSwgxJCcnTw0JCbmxZs2ag9u3bw9/7733PjGZTObU1NTF77zzzl07OzvV/qws6PV62eDgYCTDML+sXbv2DEVRFBITEzEyMgJXV1dMmCdAc2itRCK5rBnXjJpME5RKpcKPP/44r7u7O7ChoeGDgoICvPLKKy5paWlLCwsLs0Ui0duBgYFOGo0GhBCbs2fPzqIoam9ubm6X0WikGIZh/fz89O3t7XNu3boFf3//Th6Px+gMeoxrx6nX4+L2DwwO/GXnRx8hOjo6NzU1NWpsbCwjJyenjkpJSfGLjIxkKysrt5w+fbqCa20N1fCwzdHCAjAsa2ttY2PV0tISn5+fPy8/Pz+utLR0GwDcvn1b5ubm1lxRUbEpKSmJ6ezslFIUBYPBwFm2bFl7QEBATX9/P2bOnCkaHR21X7VqlUaj0TRfuHDhS7lcXldUVJTKsixHMz5u+0bCGwd+rqnxP3f+HA4ePLhRoVDEDA8P98TGxh6kli1b1rp69WoSGRmZnZqaGuXm5ob09HRub28vUlJSXHk8noGiqJMajWbo2rVryMvLIx0dHYiNjf1zY2Mj3n//faJQKPDhhx/aNTQ0YOPGjfZdXV36sLAwdHd3w9PT8zMvL68ijUYDd3f3Nz09PRM2bNgg0ev1cHNzMwUFBZ0khCAvL4+2sbFBVlbWrvHx8dLQ0ND/CgoKKqIIITCZTNDpdOzExAQIIZiYmABFUQ+9sZubG6qqqkhwcDBRqVSor68nV65cocbGxmBtbY3Ozk4EBARg9uzZ8PX1RXJyMrejowMGg4ESCATk9u3bdFlZGRUcHExGR0cptVqNGzduAAAYhgGARyr7DMNMVvgfHwcnf2QwGMCyLFpbWy/V1tayAHDixIkmd3d3/sjIyJ+8vLxw/fr1i93d3dNHR0exefPmyqVLl04hhIRRFCW9efPmC19//fWSRYsW2ZpMpoy5c+fasyz7H1qtFjdv3oTZbH62QC2RSBATEwOZTAY/Pz/w+XxGpVLh+eefh7u7+9jIyMhOuVxe7enpCZlMdr6goODwihUrbF977bXs2NhY9t69e9xDhw5RSqWSTExMGMbHxykrK6vb1dXVO1asWHEtPDwcCxYsQEBAwNMXE62srGA2m6FWqzEyMoKRkRHodDqBRqNZUlhYGHv//n2RXq+vLCkpScnNzc328fHJ7uvrm7Fv376x/Pz8j6urq/+zvLzcVy6X31WpVAkymWzDggUL7re2tro0NzcrMjMzcyoqKkAIgUAgAE3T8PHxgUgksmyCdnZ2eNDThIGBAfT39yMpKWluSEjI+XXr1p359NNP/aKios6HhIR8kpycvHn+/Pk4duyYs1gsRmRkpGzatGkH1q9ffzQ0NHR8+fLlSYmJibFarRYJCQm7kpKSzixcuHCjvb39tebm5ocmtaenB0aj8eGZPTn+j5rzjorqXNv+tffsmT2NoQ0gQxOpIihiA8UCImowMUok9gLRqNFgmpojRgWjxhqjomhsQREERawYFYgkIihjAZEOIr0MZXp//1BcOd85J98xmrzrfdb6rVnz59zzrL2f57qu+35tG+LPJJWSkpKwZMkSfPDBBygsLMSJEyewcOFCrFy5EnPnzvXy8fEZ+/XXXwd9svyT0GlT3w/csvnbz8eNGZsz0NunbaC3jzZqUWRCyplkz8J794nCe/eRlpqGxMRELFmyBDExMfj4449RXl7+RnbH326T/NmlVCoxYcIExMXFgcPhwNfXt4HP58efOnUqK/1C+vWCgoLc+Pj4XdXV1WO1Wq25TqdTZmdnv7d37974PXv2LLubf9em7nkdzwgjm8lkvjprqNVqQqlUsl4np/Q2+NsKSBCEjaWl5SoTExNuc3Mzbt261f/27du//vzzz1c9PT33Ojo6nmGQL67wPB6vNSYmxnXKlClUZGSk4OzZs7ZLliwJDggIiB82bFiLh4eHXKlQut2+fTs/MTFRU1VVlXH58uV1ERER9T/99NOy6upqvI658iaQfySWvCkGgwEajQZ5eXlfX758ufnhw4eRhw4dWlldXW1SVlb2dPny5YHjx48fFRAQcHh9zPrZ8+fPn240GjWzZ88OYzKZVc7Ozuh99/aecLVaHfR6PaytrYsmT548Ijo62o7NZuvi4+Pj9Hq91ZEjR+KPHz9+kM1mExRFQSAQ/KW8VnbwdZDJZOjp6eHu3bs3PzU1dcvixYujFy1aNLClpeU7vV4vNRqNUKvVIAgCI/0DYCcSYfasWen79++39/Pza3Z3d4ePjw98fX1x+vRpiMViGAwGXLt2DYWFhTA3N8fs2bOhUqn6lZSUjO494Jibm0MsFi8NCwszHD16NKa9vR0NDQ14/vz5XwLZ1taGvwKpVMpMSEjIKigoGB4SEpLs7+//g7W1NSIjI2Fqagpvb2/Y2NhArVAiPT0dFy9exNWrV5Genr5+/vz5z9PS0t6VSCQoLCxEd3c3mEwmmEwmWCwWmEwmSdM0zp07N/nixYsfzJgx47MdO3aMPHLkSP/JkydvlUql4PP5bY2Njewff/xxu5WVlcDV1RX/rbD7OpC1tbV429TU1KC0tPSj6OjoWfv373e0srLa8/z5czQ3N6Otre3VpVOj0aCiugp1z+tgYWkJkUiE4uLi0SYmJkhJSbl4/PjxfUajcUJZWdn3YrG4OHZTrC4+/oCxqqrqC4VCAS8vr2t8Pv8rc3Pz0yKRKM/Ozq50+fLl/9i5c+doiqJY/fv3v+fr67uaIIgeLpcLDofz1iFXrFiBt83KlSuxcuXKg/7+/jXW1taWFhYW/caPHw9HR0cMGjQIypcmSq/0am5hgQ5Jh+u9+/c3dHR0eBEEAYqi8OjRoxWHDx/+uaGhIfrx48cD+tj2KdyxY6f1kiVLdggEAqjV6ld3AgAoLS3Fo0ePwOVyf/3ss8/87969q01NTUVUVBTCwsIwderUtw4p65HibSOXypCWmobUlLOixR999EvB3fzFq7/8yn77ju0uz58/H9PW1jaZwWDwcnJyNt6+fVtz5MgR47FjxyoyLlzYSLNYLDabDQZJAkYjaBYLBr0eri4uaVELFo4Q8PltFEWBw2bDy8sLq1evxtVrV1FbW4sHDx6grKwMT58+RU1NTV1UVNSz8+fO42xKCs4kJf0lkP+vlvg2KC8vN8+/e/fq7l27nnGYLEHJo8fBDwvFz+uf1xedOnXK8f79+9fMzMzk77777saJEyeyNmzYQHzzzTdOY0aPXsYiqTZFjxSkEaApJgxaHUgj0FD3/IN9+/ZJKioqJtFsGiSDAb1eD6lUitaWVpSVlcFaaIVhQ4ZipH8A2lvb1vx4+MjRQwcPsq5nXkd1VTUqKyrfOqRKpcLbRqlUdloKhes4bLaMYlBQqdQYOmzo1fT0dO6nn356auHChTA1NQVJktBoNFAqVWh4Xl8nVygOCftY3zCQgEqngZ2T49Wp0943/3LN6iGhYe98SjCpC2dSUuLnzJ7z8MSJE+4sFgs0TYMkSSiVStzKzoK9gz1Onjz5ydWrV7+RSCRONE0vv379enJ+fr5dQUEB3jb/dRbldairq4Ori0u1tY1Ns1KlVJqamVbdunVrUmlp6dCX6jq4XC4sLS0xb+48DBs2FAEjR+KLL79E6KTJv7a1t+PDWbP+cfz48bCV0dFdA7y9xSZ8/j6RSBQZFRXZj8Fg+I4aNaq8pqbGMS4u7lZTU5MxIyOjJy8vTzkhNNR4J+/OfjabDalU2ufEiRObpk2b9u3IkSMb/l2L3ZtCTps2DX8F4eHh3YMGDbq+LiZm+qpVq1xjY2MFlZWVQrFYTKtValy5dBmZV69B2tMDnVaLX37JwaNHj0CQSN2wYePohQsXbm1qaUZHpwSGf5KiXwlcYLFYdevWrRu/c+dOe1dX1ywmk8nmcDgwGgGtRgtTgWnVvHnzXFhMVlFzUzM62jveOuSljAz8FaScOQPnvn1XMRiMzObmZvD4fDlN05n3Cu6Zx8ZuSu3o6Biu0+nAYDCg1WjBYrLQ2Niw7M6dOwf8/Uf8Wltbi5aWFjQ2NkKlUcHN3Q1ajQbOfftic1wcHO3sYS4wg7XQCv09PBtgMNaqFEoY9Qa9wNS0U6aUY8jwoacCRo1s5wn4MLM0/0sgX7ft6XUgCAI2trYYNXYM+tjaYso7YQh7553msHfCVmZmZiYlJCQYExMTTx04cODXAwcOGA8fPhxvZmaWdSEjAzdu3MCVK1dQVVUFka0IJ3/6CXfy7+JCxgUwKSbqGxrQ1t6Grq4uzu7du7eLRKKmVatW2a1fv55avmyZxe49u+2DgoK2tre3Q6FQ/GWQQSHjERQyHsEhIRg/YQLGBQdjbFDQGzMuOBiBY8ZAKBSCw+HA3Nyccfr06fmxsbGFP/zwQ61EInFhsVgoLCycU1lZOYrFYoFJMWFvb6+0srKCVCqFi4sLvLy8oNPpQNM0eDweLl26BGlPD5RKJc6ePbu+rKxsUVRU1Go/P7/v3NzcmkJDQ8kpYWGwtbFt4HG5ai6Hg7eJQCAAQbxotW1sbATJNzEBl8fDo6LHOJOSjF9yb4PmsF/Z3382rfv7xsCXQoCewWD85OXlNWTq1KnsLVu22Hh4eIQOHjx4q16vV1EMCiAIpKWlxaWmpt5vaWn50WAwuOj1emZ7e7ubRqMxA8Bj02y6rKzs/djYWElubm5sQkLC1JSUlONZWVlrSJIUyOVyg06ng5urK/wG+2Ggz8A3ZojfENAsFmQyGQQCARRKBYqKiv5Z8e39oQRBgKZpFBUXI/1iBjo6OqDVav/Jz3uTZTQaodPpAKBVq9XeCAgI+Mfp06c58xfMn8Zms+umh09POH/+/NDw8PCPaJquAqA1NTWtCAkJ+YLL5crUGo3q8tUrBwYOHJgxb968Ue++++4kNze3RZaWlt8ZjcbutyC7gSAIPH78GEVFRZBKpVBrNaisrkZpWdmLGvwuXPEfk/sEQYBBki/GbbS1Yf369ViwYAHEYjFomn51sX/dgvYGCnrtIr1OD61WC1tb2wtjxo5xcnVx3UIQBPz9/RESEgIHBweGmZkZ3djYuH7u3LnEiZMniNCJE+2mvv/+IiaTeUej0Rh7rZ8/s7hcLnQ6HeQve4GkUimio6Nx4MABpKamoqWt9d/mU17LXicIonfgB6RSKe7du4ebN29i6dKlOJN8Bmwu51/axH4Pg0mhW9oDvsAE08Knw0JoifuFhRjuPwJcPg+NTU0Q2dvBxcUFz58/x+7du5GbmwsOhwOdTqcnCEKt1WrR09MDqVQKpVIJSacEKrUaNn1sQJAk5Ao5nj59imd1z9D4u9EA/wkj+WLUwKxZszBz5kzcu3cPKpUKJEm+1sb4U4o0SZLoldPVas1/FfhpaWlBV1cX2Gz2i2iL0fBiBxr06O7pRl1dHezt7VFaWor09HRQFAUWiwWBQICcnBzk5OSAw+Fg586dKC8vR0dHBxRKBRwcHUGQBHqkUtwrvI+npaWoqa39/28KvGjiIUnytTMTbyUF9abLaDSCyWRCp9OxtVptoFgsjr5169YWLpcbN2fOnK/r6+tXJSYmrk1JSfm6sbHx8/Dw8H8oFIpvtVrtRiaTuairq2sARVHMP/Ic/471txbwZdgFra2tM5qamg4LBIJIAHypVPprSEjIgUGDBiX7+PjUMpnMltDQ0ANTpkzZNmnSpK2hoaG7DQaDjMvlPrO2tr6xcOHCU7NmzXoil8udsrOzv/rtt9/imUzmOAaDQfyfKyBB4A+fF71hQqVSOTwvLy9tx44dYU5OTqmzZ8/eQ9N05ZQpU9qFQiGys7OpxMTEo2KxOEAikVicOnVKdPz4cRQXFyMzM3PspUuXNkkkkgGWlpZ9mpqadFVVVbCwsKiMiIjYGRwc/InRaMwpKSlZLBaLj2m12j69L7o/giDJ/90CslgslJeVo6qyCnw+HzRN/wt8Ph/l5eWDXFxcOrdt2zZXpVJ119XVET09PU/z8/ODZ86cefKXX35BTEyMKjo6emtXV1dXWVlZ9/jx403mzp0LLy8vDB06tGbp0qUjIyIioqdOnXpu7NixaGpqmpCbm5tz7do1Q1FRkcHa2nra+++/f3jQoEGRWq3WrLKy0vz3A+RqampQW1uLZ8+evfheXQ2lQoE3zFm+WQF7c44qpRKtLa1QyBW9chbUajWEQiGYTCa8vLwe8fn8ip6eHlVwcDB1586d+ydPntyv0+lcpk6dGrd48WKkpqb6XblyxVOlUukCAwN5FRUV/SZPnhwUHx8/rrm5ebRYLJ6dlJS0Iysr6+OkpCThvXv3bvj5+Y2ztbWdcv/+/YqIiIj7H3zwAby9vUHTdCmfz+8UCATgcDgoLS1FQkICysvLkZ+fD5IgYGluCYqi/m0n/N/+DCQIAkyKQklJCa5du4acnBxs3rwZH3744Qvn6nfZYB8fn5xVq1YNOXLkyAq1Wr354sWLKw8dOhSkUqnE/v7+W7hc7lpTU9PvfXx8LjIYjGwnJ6ecgICA0waDYb1IJPpq+PDhCf369ZMaDIbVXC73GxcXl+tr16716+npaaqurkZHRwdMTEzQ3NyMkpISnD17FvHx8WhoaACDwXhxpiMI/Fc91n+mgAwGAzRNv9G/YzQawWAwwOPxIJVK8eTJEzx58gT5+fkQi8UoKChAYWEhMWDAgIaenp5oFouVPXz4cFhaWqKkpATFxcUwGAxYtWoVysrKsHDhQtTX1+PGjRtITk6GVCpVmZubb9fpdN+eOXOmz5EjR+TffvutrrCwEI6OjrCwsEBPTw961Z433WV/WECj0Qi9Xo+6urqInJwc8bFjx2rDw8M7165dq21qblpjNBjBZDItCIJYqtfrN1IUNZCmabBYLEej0bjWYDB8RZKko9FoBE3TvYazCYAVer1+rVqtNu/tIenq6oJCoaDq6+vnb9myJU6n0wXGx8dj+fLlcHR0hEwmGwFgO5PJnE1RFK3X68Hn8115PN5GjUazXqPR7G5ra9vc3t4+2dPTk3J3d9dPnDixoW/fvh8ajcaNHA4ntPeF9jIAZ9bd3f2xTqf7XiaTbZVKpYEk44XX8jJuakGS5Gd6vX6TQqHweRl1pQmCWEhR1ApTU1Oax+OBpmmo1eqxYrF427Fjx85lZmYe1Gg0mwCIyIKCgpC5c+dW37x585MNGzYM37FjR9+kpCTz3NxcpshWlJWVnYWWlhYJn8/3l0gknzc1NbVv2LAB+fn5zWq1eh5JkjN4PF5da2srLCzM4evrC6VSGdDZ2flJV1fXp5cvX96s1WrB5XIhFouRnJysq6ioEBIEsS49PT2jq6vLX6lUoqCgwO348eNX9Hr9VxUVFaMSEhLUgYGB2LRpUyWA8Vwu96NLly6tjYuLiyspKVm7f/9+TVJSkseFCxeMUqmU1dHRscHExISuqamBSqXC9evXj+3du/fBkCFDzs2dO3dVXFzc17dv3160/bvtxtKysjGPiotQVlYmsbCwGNenT58ZW7dufZCenv7R48eP1RwOh75x84Zrbd0zNUmSmDNnzoWDBw9eMjMzS/D29g738fFZFhcXl9ja2upI7tmzZ0l3d7ezn5/fpaamJl1FRUVvKyk8PT3vBY0dB5qmwWAwVEql0uRu3t0kDptzTSwWn29qanLS6/VGlUrF0Gg0IEgSnZ2d/VJSUnY5OTnN6Nu3b1xeXt7y6urqKTKZDOHh4YiJiYGVlZXjhAkTFk+ePHn32rVrk1taWiwzMjI2DBs2bBpFUXdVKpXX4sWLYWFhgaamJg4AD4qiDPX19QPy8vLiHj9+PGz69Olrk5KSykaMGPEqxUjTNFFXV4d58+bZZWZmLpo4ceK10NDQ9mnTpsHDwwMbN25cZWNjI1uzZs3S7777DmYvmugMQ4YM+TImJsZl3759e7Kysr53cnLqWb5suTb93Hm0trZi8eLFs4KDg3cWFRX9Fhsbazx06JB+165dh4RCoYJcs2ZNnL29fXZqauqO1NTUjzo6OmBjY4OHDx9CIpHY9+3nzJIp5NAbDWyeCV/m7NpvrrWtzWQzC/MPmDSrmclm6cwtLfQUi4lnz57Ru3btSpw0aVJcc3Nzcd++fY97eXlduXz58g5XV1feoEGDYGdnB1tbW2F9fb1m/PjxX1tbW9dGRka29+/f/3FQUFCuq6trucFgcCEIgi2Xy2Fqaqp5eT9VslisB7m5uav9/Py4Hh4e22/evImCggLQNE1SFAW1Wq1zdnZGSkpKw6xZs9YnJiYuy87OnlVeXo7s7GycPXt2mUQioffv379vw4YN6JHLQFIMo1KtIgb6DnqW+fN1i8IHYvc9e79PYtIstd5oQG5uLi5evDgjMDDw2PLly0UjRowgoqKi+jY3N/ump6fnkWPHji1KT08PjoiIcDUxMXG+c+dOfmRk5JPMzMzjPB7PGYBm4MCBvCFDhqRFRESseu+99/jr16/HmjVrzObNm7dp3NhxP1AUZWVjYwOFQjFh5MiRP3l7e9+Jjo7G4MGDdePGjTsYFha2s6SkZFxbWxskEomtnZ3djaFDh7br9XpGTEzMjMjIyCgLC4tdKpXKKjAw8OqkSZO+kclkbtXV1UhLS3N45513vhg+fPjWlpYW13379mHdunUQiUTg8XhYvHgxIygoqDEqKmoel8tVubm5gaZphIaGbvbz8+M2NDQokpOTtxcVFa1lsVgZKSkpLG9v7zxnZ2f09/Q0Gzx4cKKDg0NPUVERpdFotElJSe9s3779/e7u7p+3bNmC0NBQzJw5M/fmzZuRaWlpPygUikOlpaXLvb29J/7www88UqfTQaFQQK/XVzk6Oq7bvHnziNjY2AFubm6LbGxscg0GA3Q6ndzMzOyyjY3NUZ1OVyqTySCTyZqFQmGiSCRKAdCmUqkgEAgu+/r6Jty7d68+JycHIpFIx2azr9jb2x/l8XhXbt++jbt37zapVKqTDQ0NV2tra/X19fVtVlZWx9Rqtb6ysrKNoqiUAQMGnNBqtUWWlpZwc3Or7d+/f2JnZ2diSkpK5cmTJ3H//n0wGAzI5XKkpKTouVzuz/379z+l0Wiyzp07h6SkJHR0dGD06NFKjUaTYWVltZrBYGyzt7cv6+zsRGNjI9RqNfR6fZdQKEzn8/m5BoNBR1EU+Hw+LC0tM/r163fbw8MDQqEQQqGwxt7ePtbMzOxTiqKWikSir2maLlQqlW92DjQYDDAxMQGTyYSZmRl8fX3h6enJbW1t3a3T6b4wNzeHn58fBAIBhEKheWdn53eVlZX7Ojs7Nzc1Ne3r6up6t76+vjeNTTQ1NcVWV1fv4PP5hImJCWxtbSESiYiKioqIysrKY62trSdra2t3azQa4cu3vV9ra+tpJpM5SiAQQCKRhFVWVh6xtLR0YrFYkMvlK4qKik6oVKqNHR0d28rLy5dWVFSQ5eXlyM3NRXFx8RsLxOSfOeNRFAUejweFQoHU1FTs3LkTO3bswPbt27Fr1y5FcXGxr0wm412+fBnZ2dlIS0vDl19+2ZmcnDzex8fHYDAYTtvb2x92dHS8FBQUhBUrVqBv376hUqn0WUVFhdlvv/32uUKhQGRkJGfevHmlSqWSeu+99yIXLFiwIDw8/AtnZ2fJw4cPsW/fvu729vax+fn51J49e3Dq1ClDfX39mJEjR3YEBQWBxWKZNTY2jomIiMiYMmXK+QULFiSMGzfOEBISgpCQEIwYMQI+Pj4gSfLVfJi/tIAGgwEkScLZ2Rn9+/fH9OnTERcXh61bt2LLli2vPh0cHLRarRYhISEIDQ1lzJ8/n5eTk4MBAwboTExMSkNDQ58GBwcXDR482IzH46GwsNDxxIkTyyUSic5oND6/evXqpzKZzN3Hx0dJkqRGIpF4hYWFwcPDw2Tnzp3F58+fXymRSEDTNHQ6ndHKyso4c+ZMBAUFMTQaDUuhUDA6OjqgUqm0Dg4OtRRFPTAYDAUtLS2mDx8+pPLz8yGXy8HhcMDlcjF06FBMmjQJXC4XGo3m1fCdl9bD2ymgXq9Hnz59Xt0tnzx58i+ZmCdPnqCoqIgVEBCQ4OzsXJ+VlbXwypUrH8vlcqunT5+y58yZs12r1UrLy8s/evDgQVRJSUl/pVKJtrY2j6+++iomLi7u5Geffbb7888/X6rRaOxGjBgBPz8/n5qamrRt27Z9m5yc/KG7u/u7AwcOvDRw4EAcPHiwKioqyk8ul3vm5uaudXZ2Fm7dutXH29u7u66uDu7u7gX+/v5H8vLyourq6qJycnKmdHR0sAHQBEGQTCbzxYTK3/V5abVaDB48GLNnz0ZgYOCLCNsfCA6vvQN7T/n/CYIgNHZ2dufd3NyOubi4nPDy8op3cnKq5fF4KgcHh/NeXl6nHBwcfhwwYMBRGxubPL1eDzc3txtCobCIwWCAw+HI+vXrd83V1TX75exHmJmZPfT09Fzn6ur6I0mS1dbW1tUmJiaQy+UgSbLNzc3tsIWFxTYPD48TFEXJjEYj2Gw2hEJhtru7+xkHB4ej7u7uRz08PE4JBAKhlZVVe2dn54zS0lJUVlb+CxUVFSgtLUVZWRmqq6vx8jiFf+e9/M8AP9duncg9fOYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

is that true?
any suggestions?

thanks in advance
Dario

Comment: Does it work for you on iOS5? Is `UIImage.imageWithData` returning `nil`?

Comment: don't know... I'm displaying the image in a UICollectionViewCell available only on ios6

Comment: have to try without UICollectionViewCell

Comment: yes, UIImage.imageWithData returns nil

Comment: I'd guess that the data isn't being decoded properly. Perhaps you could try re-encoding it and then comparing the output to the input.

Comment: the base64 string is from a php json object response to a NSURL request. The NSLog("%@",img); of the decoded string is the same of the input one. do you know another base64 objective-c library?

Comment: have you already used this library for images?

Comment: if I printout NSData *data the NSLog gives me (null), so as you said, it's the decoding part that doesn't work...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Image to Base64 string in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that either you are passing in `NULL` for `img`, or the length of `img` is not divisible by 4. These are the only two ways that the decode function can return `nil`.

From the source code for base64:

```
if ((string == NULL) || (inputLength % 4 != 0)) {
    return nil;
}
```

I would guess that your specific issue is that you are passing in something like:

> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhUAAPAKIAAAsLav///88PD9WqsYmApmZmZtZfYmdakyH5BAQUAP8ALAAAAABQAA8AAAPb\nWLrc/jDKSVe4OOvNu/9gqARDSRBHegyGMahqO4R0bQcjIQ8E4BMCQc930JluyGRmdAAcdiigMLVr\nApTYWy5FKM1IQe+Mp+L4rphz+qIOBAUYeCY4p2tGrJZeH9y79mZsawFoaIRxF3JyiYxuHiMGb5KT\nkpFvZj4ZbYeCiXaOiKBwnxh4fnt9e3ktgZyHhrChinONs3cFAShFF2JhvCZlG5uchYNun5eedRxM\nAF15XEFRXgZWWdciuM8GCmdSQ84lLQfY5R14wDB5Lyon4ubwS7jx9NcV9/j5+g4JADs=

If this is the case, then you need to remove the `data:image/gif;base64,` part from the beginning since it isn't part of the base64 encoded data. I assume you just need to split the string by the first `,` and take the right hand part.

Comment: You win!!! that solved for me! really thank you! have a nice day,man! I'll have a look at the source code next time!