# Error Converting NSData to NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdata

i save an image in Database. i am trying to get the image and export it into a CSV file.
I use following code to convert into string but it returns null.

```
   int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, i); 
   NSData *img =[NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, i) length:length];
   text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:img encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   NSLog(@"ColName : %@, TEXT : %@",colName, text); //Text displayed is (NULL)
```

when i am saving the image, i convert the image to NSData and then insert it in database column. The datatype of column, in which image is saved, is "blob".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The *encoding* argument to `initWithData:encoding:` specifies what the encoding of the *data* is, not what the String will be. If the data is not actually UTF-8 then the conversion will fail and the string returned will be null.

Seeing as your data is binary it is almost a 100% guarantee that the conversion is encountering invalid UTF-8 byte sequences and aborting.

Though I do not recommend serializing image data to Strings, if you absolutely must do it then you should Base-64 encode the data first, as described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to use for take image from data

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:yourData]
```

And to save to your data

```
 NSData *newData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourObject];
```

I use it for saving images and other contents to my Core Data.