# Can't convert nsurl into base 64

Tags: iphone, base64

I am doing this way. but i am not getting where is wrong.

```
NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://play.google.com/stor/apps/details?id=com.ShiftSharerfree_new&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5TaGlmdFNoYXJlcmZyZWVfbmV3Il"];

NSString *originalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", strUrl];
NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:originalString];
NSString *data = [base64 originalString];
NSLog(@"data:%@", data);//[data base64EncodedString]);
```

Please guide me in above.

Comment: What is actual output and what's expected ?

Comment: Please tell how actually we convert url into base 64, some sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need a base64 conversion library, as mentioned here:

[Convert between UIImage and Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios)

I had a similar error with code for converting images to base64, using [base64 encode...] calls.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing i'd noted is that the NSData and the NSString have the same name. Could this be the error?