# How to post image without simulate multipart form

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

I am working with a php developer, and he is expecting me to post a image to him. But I have tried everything, including afnetworking and nsurlconnection. He can receive file, but the image is broken. All I know is that he is receiving image without using a form, and I am trying to ask that Can I post a image without simulate form in iphone?

Comment: Look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267539/how-to-upload-image-to-server-from-gallery-as-json-on-ios/15268014#15268014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to convert the image into nsdata

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image);
```

and then convert the nsdata to base64 string (you need to download the seperate file for base64)

```
NSString *encodedString=[imageData base64EncodedString];
```

so finally you can send the encoded string to your php server (you need to decode the encoded string in your php server to retrieve the image)