# UIImage to base64 not working

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to convert a UIImage to an base64 string and upload it.

This is my code:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 0.2);


imageDataBase64 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/jpeg;base64,%@", [imageData base64EncodedString]];


 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageDataBase64];


 NSData *imgdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithData:imgdata];

 [imageView setImage:ret];
```

When I set imageDataBase64 as a NSString it is working.

**UPDATE:**

base64EncodedString code:

.h

```
void *NewBase64Decode(
    const char *inputBuffer,
    size_t length,
    size_t *outputLength);

char *NewBase64Encode(
    const void *inputBuffer,
    size_t length,
    bool separateLines,
    size_t *outputLength);

@interface NSData (Base64)

+ (NSData *)dataFromBase64String:(NSString *)aString;
- (NSString *)base64EncodedString;

@end
```

.m

```
//
// Mapping from 6 bit pattern to ASCII character.
//
static unsigned char base64EncodeLookup[65] =
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

//
// Definition for "masked-out" areas of the base64DecodeLookup mapping
//
#define xx 65

//
// Mapping from ASCII character to 6 bit pattern.
//
static unsigned char base64DecodeLookup[256] =
{
    xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx,
    xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx,
    xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, 62, xx, xx, xx, 63,
    52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx,
    xx,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx,
    xx, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
    41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx,
    xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx,
    xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx,
    xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx,
    xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx,
    xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx,
    xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx,
    xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx,
    xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx,
};

//
// Fundamental sizes of the binary and base64 encode/decode units in bytes
//
#define BINARY_UNIT_SIZE 3
#define BASE64_UNIT_SIZE 4

//
// NewBase64Decode
//
// Decodes the base64 ASCII string in the inputBuffer to a newly malloced
// output buffer.
//
//  inputBuffer - the source ASCII string for the decode
//  length - the length of the string or -1 (to specify strlen should be used)
//  outputLength - if not-NULL, on output will contain the decoded length
//
// returns the decoded buffer. Must be free'd by caller. Length is given by
//  outputLength.
//
void *NewBase64Decode(
                      const char *inputBuffer,
                      size_t length,
                      size_t *outputLength)
{
    if (length == -1)
    {
        length = strlen(inputBuffer);
    }

    size_t outputBufferSize =
    ((length+BASE64_UNIT_SIZE-1) / BASE64_UNIT_SIZE) * BINARY_UNIT_SIZE;
    unsigned char *outputBuffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(outputBufferSize);

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;
    while (i < length)
    {
        //
        // Accumulate 4 valid characters (ignore everything else)
        //
        unsigned char accumulated[BASE64_UNIT_SIZE];
        size_t accumulateIndex = 0;
        while (i < length)
        {
            unsigned char decode = base64DecodeLookup[inputBuffer[i++]];
            if (decode != xx)
            {
                accumulated[accumulateIndex] = decode;
                accumulateIndex++;

                if (accumulateIndex == BASE64_UNIT_SIZE)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //
        // Store the 6 bits from each of the 4 characters as 3 bytes
        //
        // (Uses improved bounds checking suggested by Alexandre Colucci)
        //
        if(accumulateIndex >= 2)
            outputBuffer[j] = (accumulated[0] << 2) | (accumulated[1] >> 4);
        if(accumulateIndex >= 3)
            outputBuffer[j + 1] = (accumulated[1] << 4) | (accumulated[2] >> 2);
        if(accumulateIndex >= 4)
            outputBuffer[j + 2] = (accumulated[2] << 6) | accumulated[3];
        j += accumulateIndex - 1;
    }

    if (outputLength)
    {
        *outputLength = j;
    }
    return outputBuffer;
}

//
// NewBase64Encode
//
// Encodes the arbitrary data in the inputBuffer as base64 into a newly malloced
// output buffer.
//
//  inputBuffer - the source data for the encode
//  length - the length of the input in bytes
//  separateLines - if zero, no CR/LF characters will be added. Otherwise
//      a CR/LF pair will be added every 64 encoded chars.
//  outputLength - if not-NULL, on output will contain the encoded length
//      (not including terminating 0 char)
//
// returns the encoded buffer. Must be free'd by caller. Length is given by
//  outputLength.
//
char *NewBase64Encode(
                      const void *buffer,
                      size_t length,
                      bool separateLines,
                      size_t *outputLength)
{
    const unsigned char *inputBuffer = (const unsigned char *)buffer;

#define MAX_NUM_PADDING_CHARS 2
#define OUTPUT_LINE_LENGTH 64
#define INPUT_LINE_LENGTH ((OUTPUT_LINE_LENGTH / BASE64_UNIT_SIZE) * BINARY_UNIT_SIZE)
#define CR_LF_SIZE 2

    //
    // Byte accurate calculation of final buffer size
    //
    size_t outputBufferSize =
    ((length / BINARY_UNIT_SIZE)
     + ((length % BINARY_UNIT_SIZE) ? 1 : 0))
    * BASE64_UNIT_SIZE;
    if (separateLines)
    {
        outputBufferSize +=
        (outputBufferSize / OUTPUT_LINE_LENGTH) * CR_LF_SIZE;
    }

    //
    // Include space for a terminating zero
    //
    outputBufferSize += 1;

    //
    // Allocate the output buffer
    //
    char *outputBuffer = (char *)malloc(outputBufferSize);
    if (!outputBuffer)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;
    const size_t lineLength = separateLines ? INPUT_LINE_LENGTH : length;
    size_t lineEnd = lineLength;

    while (true)
    {
        if (lineEnd > length)
        {
            lineEnd = length;
        }

        for (; i + BINARY_UNIT_SIZE - 1 < lineEnd; i += BINARY_UNIT_SIZE)
        {
            //
            // Inner loop: turn 48 bytes into 64 base64 characters
            //
            outputBuffer[j++] = base64EncodeLookup[(inputBuffer[i] & 0xFC) >> 2];
            outputBuffer[j++] = base64EncodeLookup[((inputBuffer[i] & 0x03) << 4)
                                                   | ((inputBuffer[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
            outputBuffer[j++] = base64EncodeLookup[((inputBuffer[i + 1] & 0x0F) << 2)
                                                   | ((inputBuffer[i + 2] & 0xC0) >> 6)];
            outputBuffer[j++] = base64EncodeLookup[inputBuffer[i + 2] & 0x3F];
        }

        if (lineEnd == length)
        {
            break;
        }

        //
        // Add the newline
        //
        outputBuffer[j++] = '\r';
        outputBuffer[j++] = '\n';
        lineEnd += lineLength;
    }

    if (i + 1 < length)
    {
        //
        // Handle the single '=' case
        //
        outputBuffer[j++] = base64EncodeLookup[(inputBuffer[i] & 0xFC) >> 2];
        outputBuffer[j++] = base64EncodeLookup[((inputBuffer[i] & 0x03) << 4)
                                               | ((inputBuffer[i + 1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
        outputBuffer[j++] = base64EncodeLookup[(inputBuffer[i + 1] & 0x0F) << 2];
        outputBuffer[j++] = '=';
    }
    else if (i < length)
    {
        //
        // Handle the double '=' case
        //
        outputBuffer[j++] = base64EncodeLookup[(inputBuffer[i] & 0xFC) >> 2];
        outputBuffer[j++] = base64EncodeLookup[(inputBuffer[i] & 0x03) << 4];
        outputBuffer[j++] = '=';
        outputBuffer[j++] = '=';
    }
    outputBuffer[j] = 0;

    //
    // Set the output length and return the buffer
    //
    if (outputLength)
    {
        *outputLength = j;
    }
    return outputBuffer;
}

@implementation NSData (Base64)

//
// dataFromBase64String:
//
// Creates an NSData object containing the base64 decoded representation of
// the base64 string 'aString'
//
// Parameters:
//    aString - the base64 string to decode
//
// returns the autoreleased NSData representation of the base64 string
//
+ (NSData *)dataFromBase64String:(NSString *)aString
{
    NSData *data = [aString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    size_t outputLength;
    void *outputBuffer = NewBase64Decode([data bytes], [data length], &outputLength);
    NSData *result = [NSData dataWithBytes:outputBuffer length:outputLength];
    free(outputBuffer);
    return result;
}

//
// base64EncodedString
//
// Creates an NSString object that contains the base 64 encoding of the
// receiver's data. Lines are broken at 64 characters long.
//
// returns an autoreleased NSString being the base 64 representation of the
//  receiver.
//
- (NSString *)base64EncodedString
{
    size_t outputLength;
    char *outputBuffer =
    NewBase64Encode([self bytes], [self length], true, &outputLength);

    NSString *result = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:outputBuffer
                                                 length:outputLength
                                               encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
    free(outputBuffer);
    return result;
}

@end
```

Comment: can you post the method `base64EncodedString`?

Comment: Try [link](http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-base64-encode-decode.php)

Comment: Just so you know, the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` prepended to the encoded data is used to insert local images into HTML markup (and emails IIRC).  As most people have given you the long answer, the short one would be, remove the prepended string, and only prepend it should you want to load your imagedata into HTML you've written to be displayed on the device.

Comment: imageDataBase64 is not a URL. You are just specifying the type of data and encoded format. So it will not work for NSURL. The image is stored locally or downloading it from remote server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicated question!
Try this link: [Convert between UIImage and Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios)

In summary you need to encode the NSData to a string using a base64 category such as this 
https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64/

The category provides the following methods to the NSData class which you can use to convert NSData to NSString (base 64 encoding) back and forward.

```
+ (NSData *)dataFromBase64String:(NSString *)aString;
- (NSString *)base64EncodedString;
```

Try changing this line:

```
imageDataBase64 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/jpeg;base64,%@", [imageData base64EncodedString]]
```

to

```
NSString *imageDataBase64encodedString = [imageData base64EncodedString];
```

To decode it you can use the opposite method:

```
NSData *theImageData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:imageDataBase64encodedString];
UIImage *ret = [UIImage theImageData];
```

Comment: you need to decode the data not reencode and a duplicate can be reported

Comment: You encode an NSData to a base64 string. Have a look at this link to understand what that means. http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/encoding-and-decoding 
I am not familiar with reporting duplicates. To my knowledge you post the originals as an answer.

Comment: he got the encoding part right. he needs to decode the data he wants to feed to the image

Answer (score 0):

you would have to DECODE the image data before initing a UIImage with it. UIImage doesn't transparently handle base64