# Suggestion Example on image and file uploader for ios development

Tags: ios

Currently i am doing an ios application that allow user to upload file or images but i no
idea how to start. i need some kind of online server that can allow me to temporary keep
the upload file or image and can retrieve back. Any simple example can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload images using **Base64**. First you have to add **Base64** into your project from [here](http://www.imthi.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/base64.zip). I added an example code here.

```
- (void) uploadImage {

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebpage.com/upload.json"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:1000.0];

    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/design%i.png", docDir, designNum];
    NSLog(@"%@",path);

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]);
    [Base64 initialize];
    NSString *imageString = [Base64 encode:imageData];

    NSUInteger length = [imageString length];
    NSUInteger chunkSize = 1000;

    NSUInteger thisChunkSize = length - offset > chunkSize ? chunkSize : length - offset;
    NSString *chunk = [imageString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(offset, thisChunkSize)];
    offset += thisChunkSize;

    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"design",@"design_id",@"fragment_id",nil];
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:chunk,@"design_id",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", chunkNum],nil];
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDictionary options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    [self startAsyncLoad:request withTag:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tag%i",chunkNum]];

    if (offset > length) {
        stopSending = YES;
    }

}
```

You can also refer this:

[Convert between UIImage and Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios)