# Objective C to JS Bridge for image

Tags: objective-c

How do I send UIImage that I take from Camera Roll to html?

I'm able to send string right now using this library "https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge", I'm just having a hard time trying to send a UIImage.

Thank you,
Tee

Comment: Check out the new JavascriptCore frameworks in iOS 7. It makes tons of Javascript/Obj-c stuff possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out. I had to convert the image into base64.

Comment: Hello, How did you do that? you have some code to share please ? i m working on it for long time but i couldnt figure this out, i need to send UIImage to javascript but i cannot do that yet .  Thanks in advance

Comment: I finally figured this out, encoded and decoded as you say, so i vote it up. Thanks for tip. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios   this link is very helpful.