# how to get array in php send from IOS APP to php

Tags: php, ios

i am sending an images array from ios app to php server.at php i am getting a string containg data instead of array. how to i get array sent from ios in php.

here is my IOS CODE:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@questionaire/SaveQuestionaireAnswer", OtherBaseServerURL]];
    NSLog(@"submit ans url : %@", url);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"--------------------BOUNDARY----------------------";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // userId
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userid\"\r\n\r\n%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userId"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // answer
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"answer\"\r\n\r\n%@", choiceStr] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //answere mail
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images\"\r\n\r\n%@", ansArray] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSLog(@"request str - %@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:body encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);

    // now lets make the connection to the web
   submitAnsConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request
                                                     delegate:self];
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
$answer=trim($this->input->post('answer'));
$images=$this->input->post('images');
echo "<pre> w/o json decode";  print_r($images); echo "</pre>";
```

Here is my response in php:Array
(
    [userid] => 165
    [answer] => women
    [images] => (
    "img2.png",
    "img4.png",
    "img5.png",
    "img7.png"
)
)

and if i check length of array images i get result 1 instead of 4.

```
<?php  echo sizeof($images) ?> i am returned 1.
```

Comment: what are you getting from ios side?echo and print the result here.

Comment: your array is not clear.check it again

Comment: @user2936213: here is my post array:Array
(
    [userid] => 165
    [answer] => women
    [images] => (
    "img2.png",
    "img4.png",
    "img5.png",
    "img7.png"
)
)

Comment: @user3143770 You can edit your own question. Please put more info into your question, not appending in comment.

Comment: what is this `How to Answer`?

Comment: @user2936213: i have added response of php code in my quesstion.

Comment: if you what to send an array of images from ios app, try converting the image into base64 string (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios)then form json string and then send it to server its very neat and clean method to perform

Comment: do you want to extract all the four names inside the images?

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"..%@", ansArray] will replace the %@ token with the result of ansArray.description — which is a human-readable, possibly incomplete, friendly output of the array's contents. PHP can't magically understand that output; you need to convert your images to a common binary format (jpg,png) and then convert that to a safe understandable string (json/xml/base64/your call) that PHP can handle.