# How to convert string to base64 encoding in iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, base64

I am converting string to base64 encoded in iOS 7 and its working fine,but when application is running in iOS 6.1 application get crashed.for iOS 7, I am using :

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:pdfDataString options:0];
```

in iOS 6 my application get crashed on this line.Please help me.How can i convert string to Base64 encoded in iOS 6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Image to Base64 string in iOS + Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios-swift)

Comment: @Nancy please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/how-do-i-do-base64-encoding-on-iphone-sdk

Comment: Per Apple docs: "Deprecation Statement 
You should transition to either initWithBase64EncodedString:options: or initWithBase64EncodedData:options:."

Answer (score 36):

You can use this method... or you can use it like reference :)

```
- (NSString*)encodeStringTo64:(NSString*)fromString
{  
    NSData *plainData = [fromString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64String;
    if ([plainData respondsToSelector:@selector(base64EncodedStringWithOptions:)]) {
        base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];  // iOS 7+
    } else {
        base64String = [plainData base64Encoding];                              // pre iOS7
    }

    return base64String;
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work in ShareViewController if you have to share an image from outside the app.