# i Have the local path of image in xcode and i want it to covert the image into base64 and send it to the php file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i Have the local path of image in xcode and i want it to covert the image into base64 and send it to the php file.

Tha path is

```
/var/mobile/Applications/DC455F71-2024-473A-A943-504D0FC39C9F/Documents/1_1.png
```

Please help me to convert the image on the above path to convert it base64 encoding and then store it in remote mysql database.

Comment: Possible duplicate [convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios-swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios-swift/11251478#11251478)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [NSData+Base64](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64) category, and add it to your project.
After that in your Controller for example.

```
#import "NSData+Base64.h"
.....
NSString *base64 = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path] base64EncodedString];
// Request and send your base64 string to server, as usual you're sending another string
```

Or if your deployment target is iOS7+, use this

```
NSString *base64 = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path] base64EncodedString];
// Request and send your base64 string to server, as usual you're sending another string
```

Comment: Thanks but the code you send is not working the function base64encoding is depricated also

Comment: don't use base64encoding, just copy it from answer, `base64EncodedString `