# How can I send and receive an image in a php POST request to a mySQL database in ios Swift

Tags: php, ios, swift

I'm creating a an app where the user can upload a profile picture.
I need to be able to receive the image from the user, and also send it back to the user were necessary. I need to send that image from the ios device to the server and also receive it.
I've given an example of what my request would look like here :

```
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: rootAddress + "uploadImage.php")!
    var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
    let bodyData : String = "userID=" + userData.userID + "&sessionID=" + userData.sessionID + "&platform=i&imageData=" + imageData//String in question

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    var status = "error"
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        {
          ...
        }
```

the request works and everything but I don't know how to convert the said image to blob, or whatever format I need to be able to send it as a parameter.

1. Should the image be converted to NSData or some other form that I'm not aware of, and if so how do I send it as a POST parameter?
2. If I where to request the image back from the server, can it be easily converted and sent back to the device as a json object?
3. Is sending it like that safe for parsing by other platforms too (android, or webapp)?
   Sorry if this seems like a broad subject.
   Simply put if tldr : how can I convert an image to blob and send it by a POST php request?

Answer (score 0):

You should always encode binary data (images, etc) to Base64 as a general rule, when `POST`ing data:

[Convert between UIImage and Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios-swift)