# Picking image and uploading

Tags: ios, swift, post

In my app, users can select a photo from gallery to upload. After the user selects a photo, the following code gets called:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in

    })

}
```

I need to upload the image in this method, but I don't know how to upload this photo to my server. I can post text with following code but I don't know how to use this for photo/s:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "url")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postString = "username=\(self.username)"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in
}
task.resume()
```

How can I upload a selected photo to my server with above code?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called `Base64` encoding,
which could be called like this, and added to your `POST` request.

```
let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
println(base64String)
```

A larger answer for this can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-image-to-base64-string-in-ios-swift).

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Where you assign `HTTPBody`, you can use something like this. I'm writing this in Objective-C.

```
NSMutableData *postData = [NSMutableData data]; 
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileupload\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", file]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[postData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:photo]];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Sorry for my coding, as I haven't done Swift, I hope you can translate it. By doing this you can upload your image, but this is not the right way of handling server request responses in iOS. you should use `AFNetworking` to deal with these. [Look at this for more info.](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)