# Having trouble retrieving images from PubNub didReceiveMessage Function in Swift App

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, pubnub, nscfstring

I'm writing a Swift chat app using JSQMessageViewController as well as PubNub. I have no problem getting text messages in real time and display them correctly. But I'm stuck on retrieving image messages, I can send images without any problems but when the receiver gets the image it becomes a NSCFString data. The output of print(message.data.message) in PubNub's didReceiveMessage function is :`<UIImage: 0x155d52020>, {256, 342}`, And the output of print(message.data) is : `{ message = "<UIImage: 0x155d52020>, {256, 342}"; subscribedChannel = aUpVlGKxjR; timetoken = 14497691787509050;}`
Does anyone know how to convert this data to UIImage?

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert UIImage to base64 encoding and then send to pubnub message and then decode base64 into UIImage.

Encode:

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
let imageString = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
```

Decode:

```
let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: imageString, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
var image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

Reference: [Convert between UIImage and Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-uiimage-to-base64-string-in-objective-c-and-swift)