# Create PNG or JPG from UIImage (not for saving locally)

Tags: swift, uiimage, swift2, png, jpeg

How to create a png or jpg file from a UIImage (camera/gallery), my aim isn't for saving locally I should upload this image as image to server.

tried UIImageJPEGRepresentation and UIImagePNGRepresentation but they both creates a NSData, I want pure png/swift files-images.

Comment: NSData has what you want. PNG & JPEG data just happens to be the byte for byte representation needed for the file. Just use the getBytes method of NSData and that's the 'file' you're after. I don't think there's any other iOS methods to do what you want more easily.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I'll encode the image and send the encoded string to server, then only convert it back and save it as whatever format you like.

You can refer "[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-uiimage-to-base64-string-in-objective-c-and-swift)" to know more about encoding the image.

Comment: Encoding the image increases the filesize by an average of 33%. Take a look at this study: http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/