# get a string from UIImage in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have image loaded from UIImagePickerController into UIImageView

I need to convert the image into string to send it to the server

This is my code but it gives an error

```
var imageData:String = "";
        if let unwrappedImage = profileImage.image {
            let imageNSData : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(unwrappedImage, 1.0)!;
            imageData =  (NSString(data:imageNSData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String?)!
        }
```

I am getting the following exception

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

can any one help please

Comment: You can't convert the image's `NSData` to an `NSString` like that since the data doesn't represent the UTF-8 encoding a string. Do some research on converting an image's data to a base64 encoded string.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-uiimage-to-base64-string-in-objective-c-and-swift

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy your answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the data information of a image to a string , you will get a very very very long string, why not loaded the data to the server. [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) can do it easily, just see the uploading file part.