# iOS base64 encoding -> php decoding

Tags: php, ios, uiimage, base64, png

Good Afternoon Stack Overflow

I have an issue with posting an image from an iOS device to a php-webserver using base64 encoding.

I have converted a UIImage to a string in xcode using;

```
NSString *imageString = [UIImagePNGRepresentation(attachmentImage) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Fired it over to the server using http post, this is fine as I have echo-ed exactly the same string back and have seen this working.

And server-side I am decoding using;

```
$decoded = base64_decode($base64string);
file_put_contents($targetFile, $decoded);
```

The smug android guy sitting next to me has successfully put this into his version of the app and it works fine using the php script containing the above code.

Although my knowledge of base64 is limited, I have checked that the 2 non alpha numeric characters used for encoding are standard ('+','/') and as I mentioned earlier I have checked the communication between the app/server - this is fine.

Right now I am thinking there maybe a problem with converting the UIImage to a png but everything I have searched points me at the commands Im already using.

I have been on this now for almost a day and i am quick running out of hair to pull out - any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: **base63 encoding** Hmmmm

Comment: Is this any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-between-uiimage-and-base64-string

Comment: haha typo obviously - sorry

Comment: I've seen that page and its just detailing the same code I am already using, although I am sure this is issue is app-side there is nothing regarding sending this to an external server.

I am able to encode and decode fine within the app itself but once the encoded string is outside of the app the php doesn't want to decode it.