# WKWebView: insert UIImage into web page

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, wkwebview

In iOS, given a web page loaded inside a `WKWebView`, how can I show my own `UIImage` inside the HTML?

Thanks

Comment: javascript is the only way, write a script to find image and repleace it

Comment: I have a `UIImage` in memory, what URL should I write with JavaScript?

Comment: Define "in memory".

Comment: I mean a `UIImage` object I created programmatically. Something like `let image: UIImage = ...`

Comment: Just put it above.

Comment: Try to save your UIImage to /Library or /Documents folder of your application by converting to NSData with `UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage)`. Then use the absolute path to put into the image element in your html page. Btw, I'm not sure that absolute path works, maybe you have to use relative path.

Comment: Thanks _@Hoa_ I'm trying. It's a very useful comment.

Comment: If it does not work, you can try with base64 string for image. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support

Comment: I have successfully done this using a similar technique to @Hoa's 2nd one - use base64 then embed a "data:application/pdf;base64,..." URL in your HTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-between-uiimage-and-base64-string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do it is using Base64 encoding. The following should be a completely working example, assuming you wire up a `UIWebView` and have an image of the correct name:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if let image = UIImage(named: "Castle"),
            let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
            let base64 = data.base64EncodedString(options: [])
            let url = "data:application/png;base64," + base64
            let html = "<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello World!</h1><img src='\(url)'></body></html>"
            webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
        }

    }

}
```

I tried to do this in Playground, but couldn't get the webView to display, so it's a minimal app...

Output:

[image]