# How to get JSON array values in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, web-services

I got JSON dictionary, but i want to get in this son values. like NAME, SECTION,CLASS,IMAGE,DOB. how to get values and mostly how to get image by this bit code. how to show image and convert bit code to image. please help

## my Json

```
[
 {
"ID": "1000710017",
"CLASS": "1",
"SECTION": "A",
"NAME": "testing",
"DOB": "123\/123\/999",
"IMAGE": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACtWK6eAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAEFkb2JlIEltYWdlUmVhZHlxyWU8AAB0N0lEQVR4Xu29B4BdR3U+PpJWuytp1btly7ItueAOuGAwNqbYGIMN+BdCgOBACDFOQgkB0sg\.......so big code"
         }
       ]
```

## my code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 NSLog(@"get id %@",self.uid_value);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sixthsenseit.com/school/project/ios/profile.php"]];


//create the Method "GET" or "POST"
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Pass The String to server(YOU SHOULD GIVE YOUR PARAMETERS INSTEAD OF MY PARAMETERS)
NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"id=%@&",_uid_value, nil];



//Check The Value what we passed
// NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", userUpdate);

//Convert the String to Data
NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Apply the data to the body
[request setHTTPBody:data1];

//Create the response and Error
NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];


NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&err];
NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//This is for Response
 NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);
if (json)
{
NSArray *results = [json valueForKey:@"NAME"];


}


if(resSrt)
{
    NSLog(@"got response");

}

else
{
    NSLog(@"faield to connect");
}

}
```

Comment: can you show your cdoe

Comment: you get IMAGE link in proper format from webservice. change format for image URL.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-between-uiimage-and-base64-string

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik please check edit my question

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - what the reult you get in here `json` can you print this `NSDictionary *json`

Comment: I get name but with brackets. i want to print only name

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - just print this result

Comment: show all details in my view = name, image , id, class, section

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - we are in closure just print the result `NSDictionary *json` what you get in `json`

Comment: i get name but this formate (
    testing
)

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - can you print that

Comment: I  get with bracket's

Comment: but i want only name = testing

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - bro ineed the answer in here `NSDictionary *json` if you show the answer I show the output wht you need

Comment: yes i tried your code please wait

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - I m not completed my answer I need this answer from you NSDictionary *json can you print once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**no need of this**

```
 NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//This is for Response
 NSLog(@"got response==%@", resSrt);
if (json)
{
NSArray *results = [json valueForKey:@"NAME"];
}


if(resSrt)
{
NSLog(@"got response");

}

else
{
NSLog(@"faield to connect");
}
```

**Simpley Do this**

```
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&err];
if (json.count>0) {
    self.txtName.text =json[0][@"NAME"];
     self.txtClass.text =json[0][@"CLASS"];
     self.txtSection.text =json[0][@"SECTION"];

    NSData* data = [json[0][@"IMAGE"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     self.imgBig.image= [UIImage imageWithData:data];

}
```

Comment: this line is missing NSArray *jsonAreay = json[@""]; , I need the answewr in here NSDictionary *json

Comment: r u there , I need your help , just print here what your get in your console json

Comment: sorry for that because I go to home, its emergency. so this problem solve tomorrow, please come back tomorrow . and solve my problem. tank you

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - sure .

Comment: yes just print NSDictionary *json result in here once

Comment: JSON result print in console and json result show in my question "my json"

Comment: My problem is solved using a this method = NSString *name_str = [[json objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"NAME"];
  
  NSLog(@"Test is %@",name_str);

Comment: but one more problem is that how can i load image on image view base64 code.

Comment: what is the login user name and password

Comment: user name= 1000710017 and pwd = XM0MB

Comment: what is the _uid_value value

Comment: username is uid_value= 1000710017

Comment: Are you there? I still waiting for your reply

Comment: ya wait only 5 minutes

Comment: take the code in here https://www.dropbox.com/s/vzjjjkebx2v9nft/EduTime%202.zip?dl=0

Comment: please run again and check, because any user name login and same data print in labels and can't set image in image view

Comment: please print json on console  NSLog(@"my data %@",json);

Comment: tell to your backend developer give the image as URL not a String

Comment: may be not sure, or  its a simple NSString also, check once in your backend bro

Comment: any other questions

Comment: i have one more problem please solve because i tried many times but don't get any solution

Comment: problem is that i get json by server. and get JSON load in my view. my question is that json value is null so this condition my application is crash

Comment: so i want i get null value and alert show"no data access " and go back

Comment: in which page u faced this

Comment: are you there? create a new file please check https://www.dropbox.com/s/xgd474if5vrjp5s/EduTime.zip?dl=0

Comment: In this project notice page and show same data one table view. my problem is that json array is null and my app is crash

Comment: in which page it is crash

Comment: you are not attached the notice page properly attach properly and send

Comment: Notice.h and .m file attached in project

Comment: is not added proeprly in tagrget bro

Comment: download here https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zx8w1xrb0051nl/EduTime.zip?dl=0

Comment: what the problem u faced now, r u checked my updated code

Comment: now problem is that i logged in this user 1000710017, and open notice page and after crash my app. because i get json array is null. again i login this user 1000710001 and open notice page and json array reload in table view because json data is not null

Comment: i want to i get null data but don't crash my app and this condition shoe alert "no data available" and go back

Comment: are you there? this time i faced very big problem , app is crash, please  help

Comment: in which page it is crash

Comment: please login both account and visit notice page

Comment: see this it does not crash https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zx8w1xrb0051nl/EduTime.zip?dl=0

Comment: login 1000710017 and see again

Comment: dropbox.com/s/xgd474if5vrjp5s/EduTime.zip?dl=0

Comment: download this file dropbox.com/s/xgd474if5vrjp5s/EduTime.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Anbu.Kartik Do you see new link

Comment: sorry for that but i send already 12 min ago. please last please

Comment: dropbox.com/s/xgd474if5vrjp5s/EduTime.zip?dl=0

Comment: I am still waiting for u r reply

Comment: Thanks for giving me your Precious Time.

Comment: Hello sir, I am post a new question please visit one time and solve my problem because no any one solve my problem. my question url :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39270020/how-to-create-photo-like-comment-same-as-facebook-in-ios?noredirect=1#comment65875881_39270020

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - sorry bro, your question is too broad

Comment: Sir i know but how to resolve this problem. please guide

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122412/discussion-between-ankur-kumawat-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: Dear sir, I asked you specific question tomorrow. please resolve my problem. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

To parse the json try to use below code

```
-(void)convertJson : (NSString *)resSrt
{
    NSArray *jsonObjectAry = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[resSrt dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                          options:0 error:NULL];
         if (jsonObjectAry)
       NSLog(@"Name=>%@",jsonObjectAry[0][@"NAME"]);

}
```

Comment: why you increase the memory, check once O/p it is sngle array

Comment: If its a single object , why server send as array. I assumed , there may possible to get list of objects . And am just shared a peace of code. user can optimize what they want. FYI: If server send empty array, "0th index will be null".

Answer (score 0):

A good way to handle all these son values is to use a third party like [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

You don't have to write lengthy methods to parse these values. Also it handles the case where the value is `nil`.

```
let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
if let userName = json[0]["user"]["name"].string {
  //Now you got your value
}
```

Reference: SwiftyJSON.

Comment: OP tagged the question as objective-c.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri: there are similar libraries available for ObjectiveC as well.

Comment: OP main problem is to get the bitCode in the json and convert it into image. YOur answer doesn't state anything related to that.