# How to create Photo like comment same as Facebook in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, photo-gallery

I have created timeline same as Facebook. My timeline data fetch by JSON, and reload in tableview. but how to add comment and likes functionality. I tried many times but not able  to do. how to create design (UI) in which flow. I am totally confused. Please find the attachment,  [My Project File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gtc349fycthalgo/gallery.zip?dl=0) Please download and see. and tell me how can i do ,Please help, Thank you

Comment: Maintain separate section for a post and have likes , comments, images ,title and other stuff as rows. Ref instagram iOS app's timeline.

Comment: check this out for like ui [Objective-c](https://github.com/Eke/EMEmojiableBtn) and [Swift](https://github.com/lojals/JOEmojiableBtn)

Comment: You have to change your UI. First use your timeline table just to display information (photo,image,likes and recent comments). Once user clicks on a section open it in a controller and make user view details of that post. Do check instagram to know what i am talking about

Comment: @vishnuvarthan are you there, please help, i am very tired :(

Comment: Have unique id's for each post and process all comments and like with this unique id

Comment: Have each comment in table and add new comments to its data source and reload the table.

Comment: Start to ask questions on a particular technical problem you face, Asking on how to build an app wont get answers in SO

Comment: Where are you stuck now ?, be specific

Comment: @vishnuvarthan I am create detail view controller your according, then after any issue create. I am asking you. After same time i asked my problem then please help and resolve my issues. thankyou