# Getting an error when converting UIImage to NSSString via NSData

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, uiimagepngrepresentation

I'm trying to convert my `UIImage` from a `UIImageView` to a string as the data is stored as Base64. I'm using the method below to convert the image but it falls over when trying to update convertedStr.

```
func convertImg() {
    let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image!)! as NSData
    convertedStr = NSString(data: imageData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
}
```

This function is about version 10 as I've tried different ways but the result is always the same. The error returned is

> 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value' and
>
> 'function signature specialization ) -> ()
>   to @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer) ->
>   (@out ()), Argument Types : [@callee_owned (@unowned
>   Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer) -> ()]> of generic
>   specialization  of
>   Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer 
>   ((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer) -> A) -> A'

Could it be that the method I'm using requires a png file and won't work with `UIImage`?

Comment: (NS)Data has a `base64EncodedString()` method which might be what you are looking for. – Interpreting pixel data as UTF-8 string can only fail.

Comment: need to post image in server ?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-between-uiimage-and-base64-string?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Swift**

Encode in swift 2.0 and lower

```
let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"imageNameHere")!
//Now use image to create into NSData format
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

 let strBase64:String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

**Decode**

```
let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: strBase64, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
let decodedimage:UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)!
print(decodedimage)
yourImageView.image = decodedimage
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func convertImg() {
    let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image!)! as NSData
    convertstr = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: lineLength64Characters)

}
```