# How do I create an image from a Base64-encoded string in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, xcode, encoding, swift3, base64

How do I create an image from a Base64-encoded string in Swift 3? This is what I tried:

```
if result.profile_image != nil && result.profile_image != ""{
    let dataDecoded:NSData = NSData(base64Encoded: result.profile_image!, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.
        let decodedImage:UIImage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded as Data)!
        cell.profileImage.image = decodedImage
```

Comment: `let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String);
 let imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)`

Answer (score 0):

[Thorough answer here, always a good idea to browse SO first.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-between-uiimage-and-base64-string)

Basically you need to create a `Data` instance (it has a `base64Encoded:` initializer), and use `UIImage(data: theDataInstanceYouJustCreated)` and it's there.

Comment: When a question already has an answer, please flag the question as duplicate instead of answering again. Thanks.

Comment: @EricAya good point, I'm still learning as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can create one by wrapping your Base64 string on a `Data` object, then creating an image from the `Data` object. For instance:

```
if let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64) {
    let image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```