# UIImageJPEGRepresentation equivalent for Swift on Linux?

Tags: linux, swift

Need to read JPEG image format from a directory and encode/decode to Base64 in Linux. There are no equivalent libraries or utilities, is it possible to write one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert between UIImage and Base64 string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-between-uiimage-and-base64-string)

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk The question is about Swift on Linux. UIImage is from UIKit (iOS) and doesn't exist on Linux.

Comment: @EricAya I don't think he needs UIKit for that. All he needs is to read the data from the file url `Data(contentsOf:)` and encode it.