# Create Url from UIImage data

Tags: html, ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` in my app. I want to display it's image in some html content which I am rendering in app. This is a small html code which displays image in html :

```
<td class="title"> <img src="#LOGO_IMAGE#" style="width:100%; max-width:300px; background-color: #cdcdcd">
</td>
```

This is what I am doing in `Swift` to get url (I am aware this is incorrect) :

```
let logoString = String(data: imageData, encoding: .utf8)
HTMLContent = HTMLContent.replacingOccurrences(of: "#LOGO_IMAGE#", with: logoString!)
```

Line number 1 gives me `nil`.
How may I fix this ?

Comment: do you want to url from html ?

Comment: @KKRocks : I have UIImage data with me. I want to display it on html (html content as shown in the question).

Comment: maybe duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-between-uiimage-and-base64-string . You can display image with base64 by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Comment: ok you have image that you need to binding with html , right ?

Comment: @KKRocks : Correct

Comment: @user2215977 : Could you suggest possible solution from the link you shared ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let base64String= imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
let htmlString = "data:image/png;base64, \(base64String)"
```

You might then load the htmlString.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `UIImageView` named "theImageView" and a `UIWebView` named "the WebView", this should do it...

```
    var myHTMLString = "<html><head></head><body bgcolor=#00ffff><p>This is a test</p><p><img src=\"#LOGO_IMAGE#\" style=\"width:100%; max-width:300px; background-color: #cdcdcd\"></p></body></html>"

    if let img = theImageView.image {

        if let pngRepA = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) {

            let strBase64 = pngRepA.base64EncodedString(options: [])

            let logoString = "data:image/png;base64, \(strBase64)"

            myHTMLString = myHTMLString.replacingOccurrences(of: "#LOGO_IMAGE#", with: logoString)

        }

    }

    theWebView.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString, baseURL: nil)
```