# How to add image into .CSV file in swift 3 and IOS 10?

Tags: swift3, ios10

I need to preload some image  into my tableView when the app launches. So i am using core data by parsing a .csv file. How can i add those image to .csv file?

Comment: CSV is plain text. You could add an URL as string path.

Comment: So where can i store those image? I don't want to store image on server.

Comment: @Alamin This may help You [Image to Base64 String](https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html#base64-encoding-explained)

Comment: @Alamin also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-between-uiimage-and-base64-string#answer-11251478) will be useful for You

Comment: I need to add image into `.CSV` file. How that answer can help? Please tell me. @TarasShpulyar

Comment: @Alamin As vadian told You : CSV is plain text. You can't store image in it, but You can convert Image to **Base64 String** and store it as plain text and during pre-load - decode from **Base64 String** and have image

Comment: Thanks @TarasShpulyar . Now i am clear enough.

Comment: @Alamin you're welcome :)