# Formatting JSON in swift: Invalid type in JSON write (OS_dispatch_data)

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to send a post request to and api that contains a list of "items" that can be either an image or text.

However, I keep getting an error (listed in Title)

Here is the code turning my objects into JSON

```
    var json = [String: Any]()
    var jsonItems = [Any]()

    for i in 0...(items.count - 1){

        var it = [String: Any]()
        if let imageData = items[i].image?.jpgData(){
            it["image"] = imageData
        }

        if let text = items[i].text{
            it["text"] = text
        }

        if i == 0 {
            it["is_profile"] = true
            it["face_detected"] = faceDetected
        }

        jsonItems.append(it)
    }
    json["items"] = jsonItems
```

Is there any reason why this would not be formatted correctly?

EDIT:

The jpgData function

```
func jpgData() -> Data? {
    return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 0.8)
}
```

Example code that causes crash:

```
extension Dictionary {
    var json: String {
        let invalidJson = "Not a valid JSON"
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: .prettyPrinted)
            return String(bytes: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? invalidJson
        } catch {
            return invalidJson
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to my sample code, passing the created dict as the param for Alamofire requests, URLSession requests, etc all cause a crash with the error from the title

EDIT: Solution
Image data did need to be encoded.  Feels so obvious in hindsight.  Base64 encoding worked for printing out the structure like in my extension, but for network requests I  ended up using Alamofire's MultipartFormData class (a custom wrapper around it) and appended as an `application/octet-stream` for the mimetype.  Wish I could use a facepalm emoji here.  I accepted one of the two answers that talked about encoding that actually had sample code.

Comment: what type does `jpgData()` return?

Comment: JSON doesn't support raw data. You will need to convert your image data to base64encodedString to be able to send it in your json

Comment: @daredevil1234 The code you posted does not give an error. And the code you posted doesn't do any JSON processing, it just builds a dictionary. Update your question with the code that actually gives the error.

Comment: Updated.  See EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After converting to JPEG Data try encoding to base64

```
let strBase64 = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

Check this answer for more info [Convert between UIImage and Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-between-uiimage-and-base64-string)

Answer (score 0):

A Data cannot be put into JSON. The Data object will have to be encoded. Probably using base64 encoding.