# What to pass in image in this type of API for image upload

Tags: iphone, image

Here is the API   "http://flut.psites.info/api/message_image.php?userfile=image&loginuid=loginuid"

What to pass in "userfile" here in the API to upload image to server.

Comment: please specify how who want send that image like imagedata or binarystream ??

Comment: must be a base64 encoded string of that image equivalent

Comment: please post some code i didn't got

Comment: You really should search a bit more before posting a question. Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889478/uiimage-to-base64-string-encoding