# -base64Encoding return type defaults to id

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, uiimagejpegrepresentation

In my application when i try with following coding i get the warning as

Code

```
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(petAvadar.image, 1.0)base64Encoding]
```

WARNING

```
Instance method '-base64Encoding' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

How to remove this warning,Please help me to solve.

Comment: whr is ur base64Encoding classes..? have u imported it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your function in the header file.

You should add a line like this :

```
-(returnType)base64Encoding;
```

Where `returnType` is the type returned by your method, like `NSString*`, `NSInteger`, `void` or whatever your method returns.

Answer (score 2):

Then convert your UIImage object into NSData the following way:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

And then apply Base64 encoding to convert it into a base64 encoded string:

```
NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64Encoding];
```

[once check this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889478/uiimage-to-base64-string-encoding)

Comment: You shouldn't duplicate answers from another topic. Flag the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have donlaoded Base64 lib classes from [here](http://cdn.imthi.com/c70689/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/base64.zip)

then import **Base64.h** use below code snip

**For Encoding Image to Base64**

```
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 1.0f);
 [Base64 initialize];
 NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];
```

**and Decode Base64 as image:**

```
[Base64 initialize]; 
 NSData* data = [Base64 decode:strEncoded ];;
 image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Alos you may like to check [this](http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-base64-encode-decode.php) and [this](http://www.rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2013/03/convert-string-to-base64-in-ios-tutorial.html) link as well