# decode base64 string as UTF-8

Tags: iphone, utf-8, base64

I am using the base64 implementation at the bottom of [this post](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour).

If I use following code:

```
NSLog(@"decoded:%@",[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[Base64 decode:@"8fEmIzEyNDA3OyYjMTI0MTE7"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]);
```

I get `decoded:(null)`

However, if I use:

```
NSLog(@"decoded 1:%@",[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[Base64 decode:@"8fEmIzEyNDA3OyYjMTI0MTE7"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease]);
```

I get `decoded:ññ&#12407;&#12411;`

But I should get `decoded:ññぷほ`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk

Comment: ¬¬ that's what I am using.. if you follow the "this post" link you will get to the same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are HTML character references. You'll need to decode further if you want raw text.

Comment: Does it mean that coding and decoding &#12407;ぷ would not work since I would first get &#12407;&#12407; ?

Comment: No, you'd get `&amp;#12407;&#12407;`.

Comment: But that should not be necessary since I encode an array of bytes, if I decode it again and see it as UTF-8, it should not be HTML encoded, should it?

Comment: Whatever you encode should decode to the same, unless something else gets in the way and re-encodes it for you.

Comment: The problem should be the way I convert the NSData to NSString, which is in the line of code I provided in the question. Can you find any problem there?

Comment: Also, that's not UTF-8, that's Latin-1.

Comment: I do not think ぷ is in latin1 =) latin1 is west-european characters

Comment: But it's *not* `ぷ`, it's `&#12407;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you were right, it was the encoding (which btw was done by an online encoder/decoder)

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html) by Matt Gallagher. At the bottom there is link with code for iOS if that is what you are after.

It provides an class extension to NSData which is you string is easily converted from and too.