# Sending images as part of form data from an iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, forms, nsmutableurlrequest

I've managed to get simple text data sent to a server using this code:

```
NSMutableString *parameterString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString: @""];
[parameterString appendString:@"name=steve&"];
[parameterString appendString:@"surname=jobs&"];
[parameterString appendString:@"age=55"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.come/script/"];
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSData *parameterData = [parameterString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:parameterData];
```

With that I can send text form data. But how can I send PNG images as well?

Answer (score 1):

You could just convert the image to an NSData object, then base64 encode it to send it as a parameter.

Base64 encoding examples found here: [How do I do base64 encoding on iphone-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addData:imageData withFileName:@"image.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"yourParamKey"];
```